# How do I turn off equation auto numbering

Tags: equations, numbering

I have an equation like this:

```
   \begin{align}
      P(A \cup B) = \sum_{\omega \in A \cup B} P(\omega) = \sum_{\omega \in A} P(\omega) + \sum_{\omega \in B} P(\omega)
      = P(A) + P(B)
    \end{align}
```

For some reason, LaTeX is automatically labeling the equation. How do I turn that off? Secondly how do I write something in LaTeX on this site. I tried enclosing in '$' but it doesn't work.

Comment: If by "how do I write something in latex on this site" you mean that you want to write something in latex syntax to be automatically converted into HTML (as some other SE sites do), then you can't.  For more on this, read the following discussion on meta: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7/we-need-tex-markup

Comment: Similar question: [`equation → equation*`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136182/250119), [`equation* → equation`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/giving-an-equation-between-s-a-number/14708#14708). See also [math mode - What are the differences between $$, \\[, align, equation and displaymath? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath)

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Do a `\begin{align*}` ... `\end{align*}`. That should do the trick.

Comment: The "*" versions of the equation environments suppress numbers.  This is true for `align`, but also for AMS environments `equation`, `gather`, `multline`, and `flalign`.

Comment: On a side note, one needs to include `{amsmath}` package by `\usepackage{amsmath}` for `*` environments

Comment: Is there a setting to disable equation numbers for the whole document?

Answer (score 87):

If you only want some of the lines in an align environment to not be numbered, just put `\nonumber` before the end characters on each of the lines you don't want to have numbers. Otherwise, use `align*` as JCL suggested so that none of the lines will be numbered.

Comment: I think you mean `\notag`.

Comment: I've never used \notag, but perhaps that works also.

Comment: I think this is to be preferred;  it's the way intended by Latex.

Comment: @YanKingYin which is preferred?

Comment: I meant `\nonumber`, but I'm not an expert in Latex and I forgot why I wrote that comment...  Anyway I find `\nonumber` works fine.

Answer (score 45):

As a sidenote, the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, which makes some improvements on `amsmath`,  provides a way of labeling only those equations that are referenced in the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{gather}  
  a = b \label{eq1} \\  
  c = d \label{eq2}  
\end{gather}  
Some text, \eqref{eq2}.  
\end{document}
```

In this case, only the second of the equations, `c = d`, is numbered, as that is the only one being referenced in the text.

### Notes

- three compiler passes are required for the references to show up properly
- this does not work with `cleveref`, but the `cleveref` manual mentions another package, [`autonum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/autonum), that performs the same task, yet is compatible with `cleveref`.
- the manual of the present version (dated 2012/05/10) notes two bugs, one can cause that the number is printed close to, or on top of, the equation, the other relates to `ntheorem`. Refer to the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) for details.

Answer (score 44):

If you use this:

```
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

try this instead:

```
\begin{equation*}
...
\end{equation*}
```

This solution requires the use of the package `amsmath`.

Answer (score 31):

Note whilst the above answers are relevant to the question, a lot of people include equations in LaTeX using the `\begin{equation}` which works without explicitly including the `amsmath` package in a LaTeX document. However when one attempts to the use `\begin{equation*}` directive (to omit numbering) an error is generated. Thus in this case it should be pointed out that one needs to explicitly import the `amsmath` package:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: This answer deserves more atention

Answer (score 3):

"\nonumber" sometimes does not work for me. Another possibility is to do:

```
\begin{center}
$ P(A \cup B) = \sum_{\omega \in A \cup B} P(\omega) = \sum_{\omega \in A}
P(\omega) + \sum_{\omega \in B} P(\omega) = P(A) + P(B) $
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about the circumstances when "`\nonumber` ... doesn't work for me". You should probably insert a `\displaymath` directive immediately after the opening `$` symbol so that the `\sum` symbols will be set in "large" mode, as this is the generally expected behavior for displayed equation. A downside to your proposed method is that the vertical spacing above and below a `center` environment is not likely to be the same as for displayed equations.

Comment: I would strongly advise against this method, as math typeset in text-mode (ie. using `$`) and set in display-mode (ie. using a dedicated environment) have quite different spacing to the text above and below. On top of that, certain characters are typeset differently, as @Mico mentions, and even though `\displaymath` takes care of this, the spacing will remain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  Solve these problems
  \begin{align*}
  1. \;\; &   x= y+z & 2.\;\; &x^n= y^n+z^n \\  
   3.\;\; &  x= y+z &  4.\;\;  & x^n= y^n+z^n \\ 
    \end{align*}

    {\bf  This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text
        spanning a few lines.}

        \begin{align*}
   5.\;\; &  x= y+z & 6.\;\; & x^n= y^n+z^n\\   
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This gives required output.

Comment: Levesque already suggested `align*` in his answer.