# What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

I once learnt, that it is *uncool* to use `$$`, but why is that? Why does `\[` not act as a abbreviation to `\begin{align}`? I noticed, that there is a difference, since one cannot use `&` and `\\` inside a block started with `\[`.

Comment: For your first question, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

For the second: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation

Comment: `amsmath` has a coherent redefinition of `\[`. But for some aspects of the `LaTeX` `\[`, see [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179052/4686)

Comment: You should also be using `\(...\)` instead of `$...$` too.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

As I understand your question, you'd like to know what the differences are between constructing display-math expressions using the following five methods:

1. `$$` ... `$$`
2. `\[` ... `\]`
3. `\begin{displaymath}` ... `\end{displaymath}`
4. `\begin{equation}` ... `\end{equation}`
5. `\begin{gather*}` ... `\end{gather*}`.

Actually, you asked about the `align` environment. However, I think that for the sake of providing a straightforward comparison among the display-math methods, it's better to focus on the `gather*` environment, which centers its contents and doesn't generate an equation number. Compared with the `gather` and `gather*` environments, the significant added capability of the `align` and `align*` environments is their ability to vertically align equations along certain elements, such as on equal signs.

---

The **first method** is the "Plain TeX" method for generating displayed equations. ("Plain TeX" refers to a set of macros, written by Knuth, designed to make the so-called "TeX primitives" usable for ordinary typesetting purposes. A full explanation of what the `$$` specifiers do is provided on p. 287 of the TeXBook.)

However, using the `$$` method to initiate and terminate display-math mode *in LaTeX documents* is nowadays heavily deprecated. See the posting ["Why is \[ ...  \] preferable to $$ ... $$?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for a detailed discussion of why one should *not* employ `$$ ... $$` directly when using LaTeX (or one of its successors, such as pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, etc).

---

The **second method**, `\[` and `\]`, is Leslie Lamport's re-implementation of the Plain-TeX `$$` ... `$$` method. The LaTeX code that defines the `\[` and `\]` commands is contained in the file `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\[{%
   \relax\ifmmode
      \@badmath
   \else
      \ifvmode
         \nointerlineskip
         \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
      \fi
      $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK
   \fi
}
\def\]{%
   \relax\ifmmode
      \ifinner
         \@badmath
      \else
         $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK
      \fi
   \else
      \@badmath
   \fi
   \ignorespaces
}
```

Basically, `\[` and `\]` act as carefully designed wrappers around the opening and closing `$$` directives. Error messages will be generated if a `\[` statement is encountered while TeX is already in math mode or if a `\]` statement is encountered while TeX is either *not* in math mode at all or if it is in "inner" math mode. You may ask, "What is 'inner' math mode?" A leading example of "inner" math mode is the material inside a `\left<x> ... \right<y>` group, where `<x>` and `<y>` denote suitable delimiters, e.g., `(` and `)`. If LaTeX encounters `\]` while in inner math mode, it produces the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
```

(If you were using `$$` directly you'd get a slightly more cryptic error message.)

Furthermore, the command `\[` checks if TeX is in so-called "vertical mode"; this happens to be the case, most commonly, at the start of a paragraph. If that's the case, i.e., if TeX is in vertical mode, the instruction `\nointerlineskip` is executed to avoid inserting some *additional* vertical space immediately above the displayed equation.

This issue is illustrated in the following example, which contrasts two cases. In both cases, the code starts with a bunch of em-dashes, followed by a blank line (which inserts a paragraph break and switches TeX to vertical mode) and then a displayed equation. In the first case, the displayed equation is generated via `\[...\]`; in the second case, `$$...$$` is employed. Note that in the second case, some extra (and presumably unwanted) vertical whitespace gets inserted *above* the displayed equation; this does not happen in the first case, courtesy of the `\nointerlineskip` directive that's part of the `\[` directive.

[image: vertical mode demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{1in} % use a very narrow measure for this example
\begin{document}
\noindent
---------------

\[ u=vwxz\]
---------------

$$u=vwxz$$
---------------
\end{document}
```

---

The LaTeX code for the **third method** is simply:

```
\def\displaymath{\[}
\def\enddisplaymath{\]\@ignoretrue}
```

i.e., it is (essentially) equivalent to the second method, while arguably being easier to read and debug. By easier to debug, I mean that these commands are not as easy to overlook as are `\[` and `\]`.

Note that these first three methods do *not* generate equation numbers.

---

As implemented in LaTeX -- but without loading the `amsmath` package -- the code for the **fourth method** (`\begin{equation}` ... `\end{equation}`) is:

```
\@definecounter{equation}
\def\equation{$$\refstepcounter{equation}}
\def\endequation{\eqno \hbox{\@eqnnum}$$\@ignoretrue}
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theequation)}}
```

- The fourth method thus also provides a "wrapper" around the (internally generated) `$$` pair of commands, while adding a right-aligned equation number that's surrounded by parentheses. (The `\eqno` macro is a TeX macro that's described on pp. 186-7 and elsewhere in the TeXBook; it inserts an equation number given by `\@eqnum`.)
- However, do note that unlike in the case of `\[...\]`, no test is performed to check whether TeX is in vertical mode when `\begin{equation}` is executed. Thus, if you start an `equation` environment at the start of a paragraph, you may get some extra (and probably unwanted!) vertical space above that equation. This is one of the reasons for the freqently-encountered exhortation *never* to start a displayed equation at the start of a paragraph.

---

**Finally**, about the `\begin{gather*}` ... `\end{gather*}` method that's made available by loading the `amsmath` package. Before examining the details of this method, it's important to mention that the `amsmath` package provides the commands `\mathdisplay` and `\endmathdisplay`, which serve as (even more elaborate) "wrappers" around -- you guessed it -- the plain-TeX `$$` constructs. The `amsmath` package provides a redefinition of the `equation` environment and a new environment for *unnumbered* equations called `equation*`:

```
\renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newenvironment{equation*}{%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

As you can see, the `equation` and `equation*` environments eventually call the `\mathdisplay` and `\endmathdisplay` commands, which, in turn, call the TeX `$$` directive. Incidentally, `amsmath` also *redefines* the LaTeX commands `\[` and `\]` as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

(Observe that because `displaymath` is defined in terms of the `\[` and `\]` commands, its appearance too may change when used in combination with the `amsmath` package.)

On, then, to the code for the `gather*` environment:

```
\newenvironment{gather*}{%
  \start@gather\st@rredtrue
}{%
  \endgather
}
```

where the `\start@gather` command is defined as

```
\def\start@gather#1{%
    \RIfM@
        \nomath@env
        \DN@{\@namedef{end\@currenvir}{}\@gobble}%
    \else
        $$%
        #1%
        \ifst@rred \else \global\@eqnswtrue \fi
        \let\next@\gather@
    \fi
    \collect@body\next@
}
```

The command `\endgather`, which is defined implicitly, executes the following instructions:

```
\math@cr \black@\totwidth@ \egroup
  $$\ignorespacesafterend
```

The main thing to take away from examining these lines of code -- without going into too many of the details, many of which relate to the fact that the align, align*, gather, gather*, etc environments can typeset multiple, consecutive lines of displayed-math material -- is that the `gather*` environment too (eventually) calls the `$$` TeX macro, while taking care of quite a few housekeeping and error-avoidance steps along the way.

**In sum**, one thing that should be amply clear from all this is that using the `$$` constructs directly is unnecessary and even reckless, as doing so risks causing all kinds of messy screw-ups. The alternative methods 2 through 5 take care to avoid these problems and should therefore always be preferred to using the `$$` pair of commands.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: @celtschk: Thanks for pointing out the problem; I've fixed the link.

Comment: @Mico you said `If that's the case, it avoids inserting any additional vertical space by issuing the command \nointerlineskip.`. But quite to the contrary, LaTeX then issues an empty line adding vertical space and forcing the use of the long form of the above and below display skips.

Comment: @Mico why do not the reasons disqualifying `$$` also disqualify `\begin{equation}`? why isn't `\[` coherent in vertical spacing with `\begin{equation}`?

Comment: @jfbu - Please see the comment I left on your answer: I suspect the use of `\hrule` and `\hrulefill` in your example creates a visual impression of asymmetry where there is, in fact, none. (Replace the lines generated by `\hrule` and `\hrulefill` with a bunch of em-dashes to see what I mean.)

Comment: @jfbu: Indeed, it's a known "feature" (bug?) of LaTeX's `equation` environment that it doesn't take the same precautions as does the pair `\[...\]`. While the part about not producing a reasonably clear error message if `\end{equation}` is encountered while in "inner" math mode may be forgiven, the extra blank line that's generated if a paragraph break precedes `\begin{equation}` is unfortunate, to say the least. You may have noticed that @egreg regularly issues an exhortation not to start an equation environment at the start of a paragraph -- and now you know why!

Comment: @Mico your example with the extra vertical space above a `$$` encountered in vertical mode is not convincing because `\nointerlineskip$$` fixes the issue. But `\[` does a bit more than `\nointerlineskip` it creates a horzontal box of width `.6\linewidth` and this can NOT be undone!

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! One more point: are they any differences between `{gather}/{gather*}` and `{equation}/{equation*}` when package `amsmath` is in use? Which one should be preferred?

Comment: @phs - Thanks. There is indeed a major difference: Use `equation`/`equation*` for single-line equations; use `gather`/`gather*` for multi-line equations that should be centered; and use `align`/`align*` for multi-line equations that should be aligned on some point (usually an `=` sign). Do please read the user guide of the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math) package for more information about these math environments.

Answer (score 24):

`$$` is not supported in LaTeX at all, it is primitive TeX syntax that just happens to sort of almost work most of the time. The standard LaTeX classes for example all have a `fleqn` option to align rather than center `\[ \]`. Even with no options, the behaviour of `\[` and `$$` are different at the start of a paragraph, where `\[` does

```
\nointerlineskip 
\makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
```

before doing `$$`

Comment: thanks for editing, was just looking up the quote syntax, and by the time I came back you'd fixed it:-)

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 24):

The differences have been described, in earlier answers, I am just adding here for illustrative purposes regarding vertical spaces this image:

> [image: test Lamport]

which is obtained from this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\[ E=mc^2\]
\hrule
$$E=mc^2$$
\hrule
\[ E=mc^2\]
\hrule
$$E=mc^2$$
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Notice the vertical spaces added by the `\[..\]` construct,  which furthermore are asymmetrical between before and after. Apart from that the `\[..\]` does some error checking whose usefulness, IMHO, is limited to the real beginners in `LaTeX`.

Here is another image:

> [image: again Lamport vs $$]

obtained from this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
abc\hrulefill\par
\[ E=mc^2\]
abc\hrulefill\par
$$E=mc^2$$
abc\hrulefill\par
\[ E=mc^2\]
abc\hrulefill\par
$$E=mc^2$$
abc\hrulefill\par
\end{document}
```

Notice the incoherent vertical spacing resulting from the use of `\[..\]`.

---

I do not include the images here, but one can check that these incoherencies do disappear with `\usepackage{amsmath}` (for reasons which are clear from looking at the code reproduced in [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/4686)). I know my opinion is ultra-minoritarian, but clearly, only for people using `amsmath` can one convincingly argue it is better to not use `$$` directly.

Certainly `$$` is not in the spirit of the `LaTeX` syntax, but the `\[` in `LaTeX2e` is not coherent with the other math environment in its handling of vertical spacing. Thus, I personnally concluded that when I am not loading `amsmath`, I should rather avoid `\[`.

Comment: can I offer a bounty to the first upvoter?

Comment: OK, I've upvoted your answer. :-)

Comment: I think neither your examples invalidates the claim that `\[` -- unlike `$$` -- takes care to avoid inserting an extra blank line if it's encountered while TeX is in vertical mode. In your first example, note that TeX is not in vertical mode at the end of `\hrule`, hence there's no issue with `$$` inadvisedly slipping in an extra blank line. Replace the `\hrule` and `\hrulefill` directives with a bunch of em-dashes, and it becomes quite apparent that the equation is nicely centered (between the rows of em-dashes) if it's typeset with `\[ ... \]` but not if it's typeset via `$$...$$`.

Comment: @Mico are you sure? try replacing `\hrule` with `\hrule\ifvmode \typeout{VMODE}\else \typeout{NOT VMODE}\fi` and check the log. And `\hrulefill` is followed by `\par`. It is true that after `\]` or `$$`, `TeX` is in horizontal mode but this is another issue. I will check what you mean with the em-dashes.

Comment: @Mico I have replaced in my code sample `\hrule` by 15 successive `\textemdash`es and then, as expected, because we start in horizontal mode, both `\[..\]` and `$$..$$` give the exact same result. (by the way I have upvoted your comment about upvoting my answer `;-)`)

Comment: @Mico see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163205/4686

Comment: I've added an explicit example in my answer to show how $$ can lead to the insertion of unwanted vertical space if it's encountered in vertical mode.

Comment: @Mico no, this is not convincing! Yes, there is `\baselineskip` glue before the empty line created by starting `$$` in vertical mode, as in fact, `$$` should only be encountered in horizontal mode (inside a paragraph). But, this `\baselineskip` glue can be removed by doing `\nointerlineskip$$`. On the other hand the after-effects of `\[` creation of a line containing an empty box of `60%` of the linewidth can not be undone!

Answer (score 12):

Also `align` does not behave the same way as `\[...\]` regards to spacing before. `\[...\]` and the `equation` environment can adjust the spacing above the equation if there is `enough` room, `align` cannot (because of the manner in which it is constructed)

Comment: An example of this spacing difference can be found at [align vs equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325/4301).

Comment: And what is the difference between `\[...\]` and `\(...\)`.

Comment: The first is displayed math the other is a slight alternative to $... $

Answer (score 2):

An additional answer that is one of the most important for me: the `cleveref` package will automatically handle an equation contained in `\begin{equation}` but not `\[`.

Comment: Equations using `\[...\]` are not numbered, and so the concept of `\ref` has no meaning in this context.

Comment: Your posting appears to apply to all unnumbered environments, not just `equation`-type environments. For the `\label`-`\ref` (or `\label`-`\cref`) mechanism to "work", the object (say, an `equation` environment) that's being `\label`-ed has to be associated with a counter variable that's being incremented (either by the environment itself or via a command such as `\caption`). Since `\[ ...\]`, *by design*, does not increment any counters, it's not possible to use the `\ref` or `\cref` to create cross-references to the non-existent equation numbers.