# How to reduce or make the space equal of linespacing before and after the $$ something $$

Tags: spacing

How to reduce or make the space equal of linespacing before and after the $$ something $$ ?

Comment: Are you coding in TeX or LaTeX? If the latter, you should read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to.

Comment: I am using texlive (tex) and texmaker

Comment: TeXlive is your *TeX distribution*; Texmaker is your *IDE* (*Integrated Development Environment*) or, loosely speaking, *editor*. Those don't dictate which TeX format (plain TeX, LaTeX, etc.) you use.

Comment: one possibility is that you have a blank line before your display math.  don't do that -- it always adds extra space, and may cause other undesirable effects as well.

Comment: yes I understand but There is no such conditions.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel Can you show an example of code?

Comment: \begin{proof}
Also we have
$$x+2y-5z=9$$
and
$$3x+5y-8z=0,$$
where $x,y,z>0$.
\end{proof}

Comment: @DeepeshPatel Please edit your question and add the code there, not in a comment. Also, if you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Related: [Why does \\[…\\] do the wrong thing at the top of a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43868/2417).

Answer (score 3):

The use of `$$...$$` is depricated in LaTeX.  Instead you should use `\[...\]`.

You can change the spacing before an after by doing something along the following lines:

```
  \abovedisplayskip0pt                                                 
  \belowdisplayskip0pt                                                 
  \abovedisplayshortskip0pt                                            
  \belowdisplayshortskip0pt                                            
  \[x+2y-5z=0\]
```