# Avoid displayed formulas at the top of pages in ConTeXt

Tags: context, mathematics

I want to avoid displayed formulas at the top of pages in ConTeXt (in fact, my big document has several displayed formulas on top of pages), and I have read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60406/52406) on the subject.

Thus, I played with `\predisplaypenalty`, which by default is set to `0` in ConTexT. I used the following code:

```
\predisplaypenalty=10000

\starttext
\dorecurse{3}{\input knuth\par}
\input knuth text without a new paragraph
\startformula
\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}.
\stopformula
Still we have \tex{predisplaypenalty} set to \the\predisplaypenalty
\stoptext
```

The top of page 2 looks like this:

[image: output of the code, showing the formula on top]

In the source, `predisplaypenalty` is mentioned in some files, for example in `strc-mat.mkiv` where it is set to `\zerocount`. In `syst-pln.mkiv`, which is a module setting "a couple of variables to the Plain TeX values" it is set to `10000`, but that is probably overwritten (if read) in `strc-mat.mkiv`.

> **Question**  What is the correct way to avoid displayed formulas on top of pages in ConTeXt?

Just to clarify, you can assume that I use the latest standalone version of ConTeXt.

**Update** I changed the code so that there is no paragraph break before the formula. This was not the problem.

Comment: Isn't this because you added a `\par` before the start of `\startformula`? LaTeX does the same thing.

Comment: @daleif probably, I will check when I get back to the computer. Thanks!

Comment: @daleif In fact that was not the problem this time. Luckily (for me), Henri was able to figure out a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that you shouldn't set counters like `\predisplaypenalty` by hand.  There is a high-level interface for almost everything in ConTeXt.  The correct way to handle this is to set `\setupformulas[spacebefore={big,samepage}]`.  Now this is where the fun begins...

In [`strc-mat.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/2faa09e17f36cccda88b3ce144e5f2d76e092580/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-mat.mkiv#L41-L42) we find

```
\c!spacebefore=\v!big,
\c!spaceafter=\formulaparameter\c!spacebefore,
```

This makes the `spaceafter` always equal to the `spacebefore` by default.  So we have to come up with a more sensible variant, which is

```
\setupformulas[spacebefore={big,samepage},spaceafter=big]
```

If you do that the formula is still preceded by a page break.  Hm, what is going on?  Some investigation led me to find that `spacebefore` is inserted in some overly complicated manner which messes with `\prevdepth`.  Now `\prevdepth` is used by `\blank` to make certain decisions about page breaking which in this case breaks our carefully crafted setup.  Is there a way out?

Yes, there is.  As always there is some undocumented magic in ConTeXt and in this case we can simply change the way space is inserted before the formula by flicking one switch (the default is `\plusthree`).

```
\c_strc_formulas_space_model=\plustwo
```

I'll investigate further.  Maybe I find the offending bit and can show it to Hans, so he can fix it.

```
\setupformulas[spacebefore={big,samepage},spaceafter=big]

\unprotect
\c_strc_formulas_space_model=\plustwo
\protect

\starttext

\dorecurse{4}{\input knuth\par}
\startformula
  \exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}.
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I actually tried the `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` with `samepage` (I forgot to mention them in the question), but without luck. I would never have figured out the trick with formula space model. Thanks! (Also, I hoped there was going to be a ConTeXt way of doing this, this is why I formulated the question as I did.)

Comment: @mickep I think it's a bug.  Reported here: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/089719.html