# Getting the expectation symbol to behave like $\sum$ instead of $\Sigma$

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

How can I get an expectation symbol which behaves like `$\sum$`?  Specifically, I want the underscore to be like that of a summation.  At the moment I use

```
$$\mathbb{E}_{x\in A}$$
```

However, I do not like this.  It feels like I am writing a sum as

```
$$\Sigma_{x\in A}$$
```

Whereas the alternative

```
$$\sum_{x\in A}$$
```

is much nicer when in a centered equation.  (The underscore appears directly below the sigma, instead of slight infront and below.)

Is there a way to make an expectation symbol which behaves like `$$\sum$$` rather then `$$\Sigma$$`?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/4427) for finding why you shouldn't use `$$` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `\mathop{\mathbb{E}}` to get math operator spacing and limits behaviour. Or `\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}` If you want E to remain on the baseline.

Answer (score 42):

If you want "limits" of this operator, e.g., `x\in A`, *always* to be typeset as a "subscript" (to the right and below the "E") rather than entirely below the "E" when in display math mode, you may want to use the `\DeclareMathOperator` instruction that is made available by loading the `amsmath` or `amsopn` packages.

Aside: The `\mathop` directive, in contrast, will make its argument behave *exactly* like `\sum` or `\prod`, in the sense that subscript and superscript arguments will be typeset fully below or above the operator when the directive is processed in display-math mode. Do check out [@DavidCarlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56766/5001) for an application of the `\mathop` directive to your case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\begin{document}
$\E_{x\in A}$ and $\displaystyle \E_{x\in A}$
vs.\ $\displaystyle \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{x\in A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Conversely, if you *do* want the `x\in A` particle to be typeset entirely below the operator when TeX is in display-math mode, you could use the instruction `\DeclareMathOperator*` (note the `*`) instead: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}`.