# Using any symbol for "\limits"

Tags: math-mode

I want to use different symbols instead of Sigma for `\sum` and the like. I tried

```
\mathop{\Lambda}\limits^n_{i=1}
```

But the symbol is small compared to `\sum`

[image]

Then I tried the `relsize` package

```
\mathop{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\Lambda}}}}}\limits^n_{i=1}
```

But then it throws off the baseline

[image]

Ideally I want the two to be vertically aligned.

Any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT:
Both answers are great. But both have some scaling problems

Steven's solution is too big in display mode:

```
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \bigGreek{\Lambda}_{i=1}^n\foo_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n$$
```

[image]

egreg's solution is too small in inline mode (removed limits for clearer comparison)

```
Inline: $\sum \bigGreek{\Lambda} \foo \sum$
```

[image]

In practice, I probably will be using a combination of both. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer, and my OP was in display mode.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56765/getting-the-expectation-symbol-to-behave-like-sum-instead-of-sigma?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on [`\bigmaltese`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116512/4427):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bigGreek}[1]{%
  \DOTSB
  \mathop{% we want it to be an operator
    \mathchoice{\big@Greek\displaystyle\Large{#1}}
               {\big@Greek\textstyle\large{#1}}
               {\big@Greek\scriptstyle\normalsize{#1}}
               {\big@Greek\scriptscriptstyle\small{#1}}%
    }\slimits@
}

\newcommand{\big@Greek}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \dimen@=0.875\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@\relax
    #2% font size
    \hbox{\resizebox{!}{\dimen@}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
  \vphantom{\sum}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bigLambda}{\bigGreek{\Lambda}}

\begin{document}
Here's in text, $\bigLambda_{i=1}^n x_i$, next in display
\[
\bigGreek{\Xi}_{i=1}^n
\bigGreek{\Sigma}_{i=1}^n
\sum_{i=1}^n \bigLambda_{i=1}^n x_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A better method is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432/4427

Answer (score 7):

Using my answer at [How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538), I merely substituted `\Lambda` instead of `\maltese`.  While the symbols are slightly different vertical heights, one notes the limits are aligned for both the sigma and lambda.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\Lambda}{\sum}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\centering
\[
\sum_{k=1}^6\foo_{i=3}^{k}(f^2(i)f(k))
\]

This is inline: \(\sum_{k=1}^6\foo_{i=3}^{k}(f^2(i)f(k)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answers given assume that a big lambda operator is really what is wanted here. But couldn't the solution in this particular case be just `\bigwedge`?