# How to add Statistical mode in an equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, statistics

I need to include an equation that contain Statistical mode.I need to find the most repeated value in a set and also need to include range of that set.In the equation bellow,i am trying to replace max and min with mode.

[image]

When i typed `\mode` just like `\max` or`\min`,Latex is giving error.So how can I write an emaquation containing Statistical mode with limits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using any symbol for "\limits"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306556/using-any-symbol-for-limits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well what you want, just load `amsmath` (if not already done) and add to your preamble:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mode}{mode}
```

Comment: yes it worked,but now the `1<i<TN` is not under mode

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this detail. Use the `*` version:  `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

Comment: completely solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The set of predefined functions (like `\max` and `\min`) in LatTeX is rather restricted. You can roll your own by using a recent version of the `amsmath` package:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\modmax}{Mod\_max}
\DeclareMathOperator{\modmin}{Mod\_min}
```

After this declarions in the preamble of the document, you can use them like `\max` and `\min`.