# Symbol for repeated applications of an associative binary operation?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I'd like to create a symbol do deal with repeated applications of an arbitrary associative operation *. Something like:

[image]

But this is not good looking to me. The proportions on the left hand doesn't pleases me.

Does anyone have any idea on how to improve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306593/4427 can actually be used for all symbols that already lack a “big” version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bigsymbol}[1]{%
  \DOTSB
  \mathop{% we want it to be an operator
    \mathchoice{\big@symbol\displaystyle\Large{#1}}
               {\big@symbol\textstyle\large{#1}}
               {\big@symbol\scriptstyle\normalsize{#1}}
               {\big@symbol\scriptscriptstyle\small{#1}}%
    }\slimits@
}

\newcommand{\big@symbol}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \dimen@=0.875\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@\relax
    #2% font size
    \hbox{\resizebox{!}{\dimen@}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
  \vphantom{\sum}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bigast}{\bigsymbol{*}}

\begin{document}
Here's in text, $\bigast_{i=1}^n x_i$, next in display
\[
\bigast_{i=1}^n x_i=x_1*x_2*\dots*x_n
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

not as general as the one egreg just posted, but simpler:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\bigast{\mathop{\mathchoice{\hbox{\large$\ast$}}{\ast}{\scriptstyle\ast}{\scriptscriptstyle\ast}}}

\begin{document}

\[\bigast_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1\ast\dots\ast x_n\]


$\bigast_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1\ast\dots\ast x_n$

\end{document}
```