# a \sum-like symbol for exponents

Tags: symbols

I need a symbol behaving like $\sum$ and $\prod$  but for exponentiation. The best I got is

[image: exp]

Is it possible to do better? Ideally, should look like $\sum$ or $\prod$ but with capital Epsilon instead Sigma or Pi.

Comment: You could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306574.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks!

Comment: @abcdefg Although that looks to me like a logical and.