# mathbb allowed only in math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I want to type this equation,

[image]

however I am struggling with `\mathcal` and `\mathbb`,

Here is my code, can anyone tell me what's wrong to my code and how to fix it? Thanks!

```
\begin{equation}
\min _{W} \underset{(x, y) \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{E}} \mathcal{L}(W ;(x, y))
\end{equation}
```

What I am having is: The letter E, and D did not display as expected

[image]

***Solved: the package of `\usepackage{breqn}` disrupted the compilation. When I remove this line, the problem is resolved.***

Comment: Are there blank lines after the `\begin{equation}` and before the `\end{equation}` in your code? There can't be empty blank lines in `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, the will cause errors. If I remove those lines, the following document compiles fine and without errors to what I would expect: https://gist.github.com/moewew/dd09718e521ec381cf6709095147d52e

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56765/35864 to make `\mathbb{E}` behave more like `\min` w.r.t. subscript placement.

Comment: @moewe I dont have blank lines, this compiles well however the letter "E" isn't displayed as expected...

Comment: Please add an MWE

Comment: You need `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Answer (score 1):

According totally with the comments of @moewe and @DG' here I add a minimal compilable code, where you can obtain, correctly, your expected 2nd image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\min_{W} \underset{(x, y) \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{E}} \mathcal{L}(W ;(x, y))
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The snapshot is:

[image]

Comment: @kegemo and now you know why asking for a full but minimal example is more than 50% of all comments around here, we cannot solve problems without it

Comment: OK, I have found that I have included the package of `breqn` disrupted the compilation. When I remove the line of `\usepackage{breqn}`, this problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: @kegemo You're welcome and glady to help you.