# How do I use AMS Euler?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

```
% What to do here 

\begin{document} 

This is good integration. 

$$\displaystyle \int x dx = \frac{x^2}{2}$$

\end{document}
```

I don't know much about LaTeX so I am going to need some spoon feeding.

I want text to appear in normal font. But math to appear in `AMSEuler` Font.

I don't want to make any changes inside the document.

Comment: Just add the instruction `\usepackage{euler}` in the document's preamble, i.e., somewhere between `\documentclass{<your favorite clas>}` and `\begin{document}`. Incidentally, the use of `$$` to start and end a display-math equation is seriously deprecated; use `\[` and `\]` instead.

Comment: @Mico Worked like a charm! Thanks! Can you make that an answer?

Comment: What if I wanted to change font of everything to AMSEuler?

Comment: @PratikDeoghare -- the euler fonts were designed expressly for use in math, and have idiosyncrasies that would make them look quite bad for text -- the kerning/letterspacing would be uneven, for one thing. the shapes aren't really "coherent", etc., etc.  for use as math variables, every letter must be able to be understood unambiguously in isolation; it doesn't necessarily have to look good in a word, and some of the shapes would tend to "attract too much attention" when outside their natural math element.

Comment: `Euler` (or `AMSEuler`) is a math font; there's no text font that corresponds directly to it. I've read somewhere that Zapf (the designer of the Euler fonts) likes the look of `Palatino` (another Zapf design!) to go along with `Euler`. You could also try the `Concrete` font family (use `\usepackage{concrete}`); the combination of Euler and Concrete was very successful in the book "Concrete Mathematics" by Knuth et al.

Comment: wow! That book is exactly what I am trying to imitate. @barbarabeeton Thanks for the advice! :D

Comment: Just `\usepackage{euler-math}`

Comment: To use the new euler-math – OpenType version of Hermann Zapf’s Euler maths font, https://ctan.org/pkg/euler-math?lang=en.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just add either `\usepackage{euler}` or `\usepackage{eulervm}` to your document's preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{euler}
\begin{document} 
This is good integration. 
\[
\int x \,dx = \frac{x^2}{2}+c
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `eulervm` package includes many revisions by Zapf to the original Euler fonts. If you use the `eulervm` package, you will probably want to load it with the options `euler-digits` and `euler-hat-accent`, i.e., as

```
\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
```

Incidentally, the use of `$$ ... $$` to generate display-math equations is heavily deprecated; it's much better to use `\[` and `\]`, as I do in the example above. For much more on this subject, please see the postings [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

---

**Addendum**: There is no *text font* that's matched perfectly to `AMS Euler`. If you provide the directive `\usepackage{concrete}` in the preamble, you'll get the `Concrete Roman` text font family. `Concrete Roman` and `AMS Euler` were used together (very successfully, I'd say) in the textbook [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201142368), 1st ed. 1988, 2nd. ed. 1994, by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth, and Oren Patashnik. However, be forewarned that `Concrete Roman` is a "raster font" and therefore won't look very good on screen. If the font is generated at 600 dpi, it'll look just fine in print; it's only the on-screen look that will likely disappoint. Other text fonts that are known to work well with `AMS Euler` are `Palatino`, `Aldus`, and `Melior`; perhaps not coincidentally, all three are creations of [Hermann Zapf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Zapf), the designer of the `AMS Euler` fonts. To set `Palatino` as the text font of your document, you could, e.g., issue the command `\usepackage{newpxtext}`.

Comment: Why is $$ deprecated?

Comment: I'd use `eulervm` rather than `euler`

Comment: @egreg - thanks for this suggestion; I've incorporated it in my answer.

Comment: @PratikDeoghare - I've added a reference to an earlier Q&A that addresses just this topic.

Comment: Follow-up: `eulerpx` is a nice combination of Euler and `newpxmath` that goes well with Palatino (`newpxtext` or `tgpagella`) or Optima (`classico`).

Answer (score 34):

## Euler in Modern Toolchains

### Euler Math

As of 2024, there is an OpenType version of Euler available on CTAN, Euler Math.  It is a fork of Khaled Hosny and Hermann Zapf’s Neo Euler.  This is the simplest way to use Euler on modern TeX engines, but I leave my original answers below.

A MWE using Euler Math with a clone of Zapf’s TeX Gyre Pagella as the text font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%%%
% Set up you text and math fonts
%%%

\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Euler Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2 \uppi \upi} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Euler Math with Pagella sample]

Other fonts matching these are Hermann Zapf’s Optima for sans-serif, and Raph Levien’s Inconsolata for monospace.

DEK originally commissioned AMS Euler and Concrete together, for his book *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science*.  To replicate this classic look, you can use CMU Concrete as the matching text font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%%%
% Set up you text and math fonts
%%%

\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Euler Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2 \uppi \upi} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Euler Math with CMU Concrete sample]

A pedantic note is that Concrete originally had no bold weight, so DEK originally used Computer Modern Sans Semibold Condensed for the headers.

### Neo Euler

There also exists an OpenType edition of Euler, [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf), by Khaled Hosny.  However, it was abandoned in 2011.  If you download Neo Euler from its GitHub page, it is possible to use with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, but there are a few gotchas.

This is lengthy because I give many complex examples that you can cut and paste into your preamble.  They should just about cover all the use cases I’ve ever heard anyone recommend.

### The Classic Look

Neo Euler, like AMS Euler, contains only glyphs for upright math. To get the classic look of the `euler` and `eulervm` packages, or the book *Concrete Mathematics*, you’ll want to set the `unicode-math` option `math-style=upright`.

Then, you want to load only the glyphs Neo Euler provides, with a fallback math font for the rest.  Here, I use Khaled Hosny’s newer math font, Libertinus Math.  It shows some influence from Euler, especially in its integrals.  Finally, make sure to load the Greek letters as the upright math alphabet, since `unicode-math` expects lowercase Greek letters to be slanted.  It sets up the other alphabets the `euler` package does, including Euler Script as both `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`, but not all the alphabets `unicode-math` supports.  Legacy documents should still compile with this preamble.

For the text font, this sets up the Computer Modern Unicode version of Concrete.  (Note that the CMU Concrete Bold font is a recent addition.  DEK did not create a bold face for Concrete Roman, and used Computer Modern Roman Bold Extended in *Concrete Mathematics* instead.  The `beton` documentation traditionally recommended Computer Modern Sans Serif Demibold Condensed.  Today, you might try Gill Sans/Gillius ADF and see if you like it.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathup{d}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%%%
% Set up you text and math fonts
%%%

\unimathsetup{math-style=upright}
\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2\symup{\pi i}} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Neo Euler with CMU Concrete, classic style]

This is a variant of the classic [“Survey of Free Math Fonts for TeX and LaTeX.”](http://tug.ctan.org/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html)

### Extending to ISO Style with Concrete

If you want to get the full range of math alphabets, you would need to kitbash the Euler math font with others to supply the missing glyphs.  Here is a version that selects ISO style (upright sum and product symbols, constants π and i, and numerals; Italic *Γ* function and variables), retains the upright ∂ from Neo Euler, keeps all the math alphabets that exist in Neo Euler (except the digits, which ought to match the text font and have bad spacing as superscripts anyway), and supplies the missing pieces of `it`, `bf`, `bfup` and `bfit` from the CMU Concrete family.

```
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright}
\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/num]{CMU Concrete}
\setmathfont[range=it/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{CMU Concrete Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{Greek}]{CMU Concrete Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{CMU Concrete Bold Italic}
```

[image: Neo Euler with CMU Concrete, ISO style]

### Euler plus Palatino

Here is the version that, after a lot of trial and error, I like the best.

Another common recommendation, including in the earlier answer, is to combine Euler math symbols with Palatino text.  It sets the text font to Palatino, or one of its many clones, in this case Pagella (although you might have the original Palatino or Palatino Linotype).  It then fills in all the missing parts of Neo Euler with another Palatino clone, Asana Math.  It sets up `\mathcal`as Euler Script, `\mathbfcal` from the alternate style of Asana, `\mathbb` from Latin Modern Math (more legible and more similar to classic `amsfonts`), digits from Asana (as these need to match the main text) and all other symbols not defined in Euler from Asana.

We now have complete coverage of all Unicode math symbols, which allows us to set this example in ISO style.  This uses italic math letters as the default, including uppercase Greek such as the Gamma function, but leaves symbols such as ∑ and ∏ intact and sets constants such as 2πi in the denominator as upright.  (Observe that `unicode-math` is smart enough to set `\symup{\pi i}` as Euler and `\mathrm` and operator names in the text font.)  It keeps the upright partial derivative and nabla, as Euler does not define cursive forms.

You can change back to `math-style=upright` to get a more classic look that still allows you to use all the math alphabets.

```
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={bfup/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek}, frak, bffrak, cal},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={up/num, bfup/num, it, bfit, scr, bfscr,
                    sfup, sfit, bfsfup, bfsfit, tt}
            ]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfcal, Scale=MatchUppercase, Alternate]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}
```

[image: Neo Euler plus Asana plus Latin Modern with Pagella]

### Euler Symbols, Palatino Letters

This alternative uses use only the math symbols from Neo Euler and overwrite all its math alphabets, for the most consistency between text and math modes.

```
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
            }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={up/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek, num},
                    it, bfup, bfit, bb, bbit, scr, bfscr, frak, bffrak,
                    sfup, sfit, bfsfup, bfsfit, tt }
            ]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[Alternate, range={cal, bfcal}]{Asana Math}
```

[image: Neo Euler/Asana Math Kitbash with Pagella]

## Backward-Compatiblity with PDFTeX

If you cannot use `unicode-math`, it is still possible to get Type 1 fonts, bold math symbols, upright Greek, and more.  Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tracinglostchars=2

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%%%
% Set up you text and math fonts
%%%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[boldsans]{ccfonts}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\newcommand\BbbC{\ensuremath{\mathbb{C}}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerup}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathord}{eulerup}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upi}{\mathord}{eulerup}{"69}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2 \uppi \upi} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbold{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `\mathrm` selects the text font and `\mathbf` doesn’t work, so I instead define `\uppi` and `\upi` (`\mathnormal` would work until you changed the math font to something other than Euler, whereas these select upright Greek letters from Euler in any document) and use the `\mathbold` command from `eulervm`.

[image: Euler with ccfonts sample]

### Euler Plus Palatino with NFSS

The popular combination of AMS Euler with Palatino (or one of its clones) is also available as a NFSS package, backward-compatible with PDFLaTeX.  It was last updated in 2017, years more recently than any of the other packages I’ve shown off.  This uses the math letters from Euler, but symbols from `newpx` (on which the Asana Math font is also based), and uses the digits from the text font, which I set to Pagella.  It’s similar to the Pagella/Neo Euler/Asana Math sample above, if you pass the `math-style=upright` option to `unicode-math`.

The package does not load the Euler calligraphic or Fraktur math alphabets, so I set those up afterward.  If you want to add matching sans-serif and monospaced fonts, Optima (URW Classico) and Inconsolata might be good choices available for NFSS.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%%%
% Set up you text and math fonts
%%%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eulerpx} % Loads Euler Fraktur and Script since 2021.
\usepackage{eucal}

\newcommand\BbbC{\ensuremath{\mathbb{C}}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerup}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upi}{\mathalpha}{eulerup}{"69}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2 \uppi \upi} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Eulerpx sample]

There are a few oddities here, such as the spacing of ∊ and ℂ, but it’s a simple and attractive setup.

**Note:** Recent versions of `eulerpx` now load Euler Fraktur and Euler Script itself, breaking my original template (which loaded `eufrak`).

Comment: apologies because my intent was to actually refer to ``\oint_{\partial Q} f'``... I hope I didn't cause an unneeded roolback. To my eyes the `\partial` from  ``\oint_{\partial Q} f'`` is really far from the ``Q`` and close to the integral signs in all OpenType samples, but looks good in the PDFTeX one...

Comment: @jfbu No, you didn’t. I was trying to get the `\symup{\pi i}` to display as `\symup` rather than `\mathrm`, and then I realized I’d replaced the wrong example by mistake. In fact, you did me a favor by making me double-check. Fixed now.

Comment: @jfbu The happy middle seems(?) to be to turn script-style off only for letters and numerals. Not perfect. The spacing for script-style in Neo Euler is broken.  The ImageMagick rasterizer has some problems, too, and some of the images look better in my PDF viewer.

Comment: thanks for all your efforts. Regarding rasterizer I have had in the past similar experience with dvipng (I recall with libertine 8bit font) compared to pdf (from dvipdfmx). Strange offsets in letter locations sometimes in the png graphics.

Comment: Is this answer still up to date? Sorry, like OP, I'm a beginner who needs spoon feeding and can't determine if this answer from 2011 is still on top in 2018. Is there a new recommendation? I mean, the repo says it's left there for "archaeological purposes". I deduct Neo Euler shouldn't be used any more. What has it been superseded by? Is Libertinus Math still a good (or the best) recommendation to move away from Neu Euler?

Comment: @thymaro My answer is from 11 April 2018, which apparently got displayed as April 11 and misread as April 2011? The question is from 2013, but I wrote an answer five years later because it still comes up in searches and I hoped people like you would find it. So far as I know, it’s still up to date.

Comment: @thymaro I wouldn’t say that Libertinus Math was my recommendation to move away from Neo Euler. Neo Euler only covers a few dozen glyphs drawn by the great Hermann Zapf for AMS Euler (http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amsfonts), which Khaled Hosny converted to OpenType. I don’t know why Hosny’s project was abandoned, but to get it *mostly* usable, you need to load it in addition to a fallback font that contains the symbols it’s missing. I picked Libertinus Math for that because it’s another font by Khaled Hosny, and the symbols seem to have some influence from Euler.

Comment: @thymaro You might have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available/425099#425099

Comment: @Davislor so you mean that between Apr 11 (2018-04-11), not much has changed?! Total mindblow!!!eleven!! :'D No seriously, you're right, I just misread the date. Thanks for the explanations and the link (apparently, I already bookmarked that question at an earlier date). I'll look into all of that.

Comment: I wanted to implement the Euler+Palatino recommendation, but in my current mactek distribution and TeX Live, I cannot find `Neo Euler` anymore and `fontspec` returns an error. What would be the best workaround?

Comment: @SergeB. Neo Euler isn’t in most TeX distributions, but you can [download from the repo.](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf)

Comment: @SergeB. You can also try giving `unicode-math` the option `math-style=upright` instead of `math-style=ISO` to use the letters from Neo Euler by default.

Comment: @Davislor The bounty is representative for all your efforts on the Unicode math fonts answer.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @HenriMenke You’re very welcome!

Comment: The solution `Euler Plus Palatino with NFSS` faces error with `TeXlive 2024` and needs update. The error is that `Command \mathfrak already defined.` The Command: `\newcommand{\mathfrak}{\EuFrak}`

Comment: @AbbasShams The error is in the `eufrak` package. You can remove it for now.

Comment: @Davislor Do you mean remove the `eufrak` package, or remove the command `\newcommand{\mathfrak}{\EuFrak}` from the package an put it beside the main `.tex` file? Anyhow, the error is due to updating packages and seems to be permanent; so, you may want to update the answer as an intact reference.

Comment: @AbbasShams I mean, don’t load the package. It’s unlikely you actually use it.

Comment: @AbbasShams That said, ithe package is buggy and should override `\mathfrak` if it’s been set already, not crash.

Comment: @Abbas I updated my answer for 2024.