# Fontspec matching lower case between roman, mono and math fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontsize, fontspec, typography

I have been trying to make `roman`, `mono` and `math fonts` match the lower case. More specifically, I am using `Palatino` for `roman`, `AMS-Euler` for `math` and `dejavu sans` for `mono`. However, I have been unsuccessful so far. The situation that I have is shown in the picture. From the left to the right, we have the math font, the roman font and mono font.

[image: Illustration of lower and upper cases]

Here is the MWE

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common},Scale=MatchLowercase,Color=textcolor}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1} % To scale all fonts correctly

\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Palatino Linotype}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Palatino Linotype}
\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}
% Setting Euler as math font
\usepackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode,math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[bold-style=ISO]{ams-euler.ttf} %Can be downloaded from http://www.fontain.org/ams-euler/ 

\begin{document}

Upper case: $W$W{\tt W}

Lower case: $w$w{\tt w}

\end{document}
```

Would someone know how to scale these fonts so that the upper and/or the lower case matches?

Comment: For some reason I don't claim to understand, the code you've presented works -- meaning that the x-heights of the lowercase letters are matched -- doesn't work as expected under XeLaTeX. However, it does work under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Mico. However my question is why it does not work with Xelatex

Comment: As I noted in my comment, I do *not* know either why the `Scale=MatchLowercase` option doesn't work as expected under XeLaTeX. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**\begin{EDIT}{2018-05-17}**

You might want to look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425887/117274) going into detail about how best to use Neo Euler. One major thing to consider, is that Neo Euler hasn't been worked since 2011 and the github repo states

> this project is abandoned, the repository is left for achælogical purposes

so I don't know if using Euler, AMS Euler or Neo Euler is still a good idea. You might want to leave the dead rest in peace and work with living fonts. Have a look at the latest version `unicode-math` [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) to make a more educated decision as to how to best move on.

**\end{EDIT}**

---

The option `Scale=MatchLowercase` works under `XeLaTeX`. I have found by chance, that the "correct" way to do it is to follow Example 1 of the documentation:

```
\setmainfont{texgyrebonum-regular.otf}
\setsansfont{lmsans10-regular.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4-Regular.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

that is, not to set the `Scale=MatchLowercase` as an argument in

```
\defaultfontfeatures{...}
```

but rather as an optional argument of the "secondary" fonts, which will then orient themselves to the main font, which has been set by `\setmainfont{...}`

Second (yeahr, I ain't mentioned 'first', get over it), from the `fontspec` documentation, we get:

> The fontspec package must also be loaded after any maths font packages (e.g., euler) to be successful. (Actually, it is only euler that is the problem.5)
>
> 5: Speaking of euler, if you want to use its `[mathbf]` option, it won’t work, and you’ll need to put this after `fontspec` is loaded instead: `\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbf{U}{eur}{b}{n}`

Third, there seems to be a problem with `Palatino Linotype` as main font, since the following code...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Color={00D419},Scale=MatchLowercase]{ams-euler.otf}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setmonofont[Color={0019D4},Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
Upper case: $W$W{\tt W}

Lower case: $w$w{\tt w}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: lower case letters have different heights]

but if I just change the font to, say `Libertinus Serif` (I didn't test other ones), ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Color={00D419},Scale=MatchLowercase]{ams-euler.otf}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmonofont[Color={0019D4},Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
Upper case: $W$W{\tt W}

Lower case: $w$w{\tt w}
\end{document}
```

we get nicely lowercase-matched types. It also works with `MatchUppercase`.

[image: lower case letter match in size]

PS: Could anyone enlighten me as to where `\setromanfont` comes from? This term is nowhere to be found in the `fontspec` documentation.