# What is this w symbol in latex code?

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know what is the code for this symbol in latex ?
[image]

Comment: It is simply w in math mode with Times font?

Comment: Looks a bit like the w from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431983/121799).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer simply confirms the comment of the very good @JouleV user, adding a minimum compilation code and a clarification of the font used. `newtxtext` package give a font Times clone; in mathematical mode to have the same characters Times you can add `newtxmath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
w in text mode and w in math-mode: $w$.
\end{document}
```

Very similar also with `Cambria Math`, often used in other writing programs is very close to the image. See this code compilable with `LuaLaTeX`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}


\begin{document} 
$w$
\end{document}
```