# Aesthetically, which font should I use when I want to use Euler Math fonts?

Tags: xetex, best-practices, typefaces, euler

So the question is of an aesthetics "best practice" type. I know that I shouldn't use Euler math fonts with the standard Computer Modern, and I'm struggling to find a suitable typeface where I can use Euler math without looking unprofessional.

My documents usually stay as PDFs, meaning they're never really printed on paper, rather they're looked at on screens, where the display system takes advantage of font scaling, etc.

I'd like to use one of the typefaces that come in LaTeX repositories like Texlive or MikTex, I can probably get a custom font later when I really need to.

The main problem is really finding a main font, to which Euler is a decent math companion font. I'm using XeLaTeX, if that makes any difference.

I've seen someone mentioning a set of packages which combine sets of these into entire presets, however I can't find them anymore. If someone could link me to those, that would be great, too.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103983 (answer from Mico) for example: "[...] There is no text font that's matched perfectly to AMS Euler. [...] Other text fonts that are known to work well with AMS Euler are **Palatino, Aldus, and Melior** -- all are, perhaps not coincidentally, creations of Hermann Zapf, the designer of the AMS Euler fonts. To set Palatino as the text font of your document, you could, e.g., issue the command `\usepackage{newpxtext}`".

Comment: not necessarily a recommendation, but this has been addressed by knuth.  he used the "concrete" version of computer modern with the euler fonts in typesetting *concrete mathematics*; see his [tugboat article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf).

Comment: "Concrete and Euler were used together (very successfully, I'd say) in the textbook "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. However, be forewarned that this is a "raster font" and thus won't look very good on screen." taken from the link in my my first comment. Since the OP states that the document won't be printed, I omitted that part :)

Comment: Thanks guys! This already helped a ton. If any of you'd want to reformulate this into a decent answer similar to the gist of these comments, I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: Still open questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(I only quote another answer)*

User [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001) points out in "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103983", that

### Quote 1

> **Concrete** and **Euler** were **used together** (very successfully, I'd say) in
> the textbook "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.
> However, be forewarned that this is a **"raster font"** and thus **won't
> look very good on screen**.

### Quote 2

> [...] There is no text font that's matched perfectly to AMS Euler.
> [...] **Other text fonts** that are known to **work well with AMS Euler** are
> **Palatino, Aldus, and Melior** -- all are, perhaps not coincidentally,
> creations of Hermann Zapf, the designer of the AMS Euler fonts. To set
> Palatino as the text font of your document, you could, e.g., issue the
> command `\usepackage{newpxtext}`.

### Quote 3 (see comment below)

> Hermann Zapf’s Optima (or its clone URW Classico, available gratis) is a good sans-serif companion. I like Inconsolata as a monospaced companion font.

> Oh, and there now is at least one body font based on Euler: Aref Ruqaa. I don’t know that I’d recommend it, but it’s the closest match.

### Short Answer

- If you *only* print your document, then try the text font **Concrete** (only rasterized available according to the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103983) above).
- In all other cases try **Palatino, Aldus, or Melior** as the text font.
- **Al­dus** and **Me­lior** seem to be *commercial* fonts.

### Links

- **Euler** on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/euler ("[...] AMS Euler fam­ily of fonts for math­e­mat­ics in LATEX doc­u­ments.")
- **Euler Virtual Math Fonts** on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eulervm ("Euler-VM is a set of vir­tual math­e­mat­ics fonts based on Euler and CM. [...] This ap­proach has *sev­eral ad­van­tages* *over* im­me­di­ately us­ing the *real Euler* fonts:")
- **Concrete** on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/concrete
- **Palatino** on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo

Comment: @Mico: I quote you. Just wanted to inform you. If you don't like it, just tell me.

Comment: There is an outline version of Concrete in `ccfonts` and an OpenType version from `CMU Concrete`.

Comment: Hermann Zapf’s Optima (or its clone URW Classico, available *gratis*) is a good sans-serif companion. I like Inconsolata as a monospaced companion font.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks, I added it to my answer.

Comment: Oh, and there now is at least one body font based on Euler: Aref Ruqaa. I don’t know that I’d recommend it, but it’s the closest match.