# Is there any analogue of mathcal which also works with Greek letters?

Tags: fonts, greek, math-fonts, mathcal

I have noticed that the font category mathcal does not work with Greek letters as inputs, probably because nobody has created any sort of "calligraphic Greek font family". Is there any sort of font package or environment which does this?

Comment: I have never seen that, and I wonder if it makes sense. Do you have any particular Greek letter in mind that you would like to have in calligraphic form?

Comment: A whole alphabet (including uppercase and lowercase) would be interesting to see. Something that delineates it from the default Greek letters used by LaTeX users.

Comment: Do you know any Greek calligraphers (or are you one yourself)?

Comment: you could of course use different Greek fonts even if not designed for math, especially if using luatex or xetex. Random google search for calligraphic Greek fonts shows several eg https://mollysuberthorpe.com/news/greek-calligraphy

Comment: Unicode (and unicode-math package already have some distinguished Greek alphabets, bold,  bold sans serif,etc

Comment: what about Euler Math?   It has a distinctive calligraphic style, and the full (* at least full for maths) Greek alphabet.  See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103986/15036

Comment: Greek italic is in origin and design calligraphic/hand-written (see Unicode Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols, and `unicode-math`). Look at the Tex Gyre *xxx* - Math fonts, for example (/fonts/opentype/public/...). Tex Gyre Pagella - Math, e.g., ![p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Y9a.png) and ![p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm9ur.png).

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=35280)

Comment: [greeksocietyfont](https://www.greekfontsociety-gfs.gr/typefaces) Is any of these fonts helpful?