# Which math font is used in this document?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I would like to know if it was possible to know the math font used on this document for the mathematical rendering :

[image]
http://bourrigan.fr/data/td03-ensembles-applications-indications.pdf

For the written part "pdffonts" gives me the following result:

[image]

So I use the `mathpazo` package but I don't have the same math rendering.

Comment: The math font is Euler, aka [AMS Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler), which was designed by Hermann Zapf. See [How do I use AMS Euler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103983/5001) for a discussion of how to use this font in a LaTeX document.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !