# What's the difference between $$ $$ and \begin{equation} \end{equation}?

Tags: math-mode, code, output

I don't know the difference between `$$...$$` and `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. 
What's the difference between `$$...$$` and `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`? `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`?

Comment: See (duplicate) [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy) and (related) [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?](http://goo.gl/ClGXg)

Comment: Also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854) is useful.

Comment: Also "[What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath)".

Answer (score 5):

- `$$ ... $$` is a delimiter for a numbered display equation. It should no longer be used. The recommended equivalent for this is `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.
- `\[ ... \]` is a delimiter for a non-numbered display equation. It is the short version of the `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`.

Comment: Mico's (earlier posted) answer ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/78134 ) to a related question is a little more detailed, and -- importantly -- suggests that this answer here might even be wrong in some important ways (not least that $$ $$ does not give a numbered equation)