# Bad math environment delimiter when using \begin{equation} and \end{equation}

Tags: equations, matrices

I wrote a matrix equation

```
\[
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    v^{0}_{n} \\
    v^{K-1}_{n}
  \end{array} \right] = 
    -\frac{1}{C_{ref}} 
      \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} V^{0}_{0,n} & \cdots & V^{0}_{M-1,m} \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        V^{K-1}_{0,n} & \cdots &  V^{K-1}_{M-1,n}
      \end{array}  \right]
      \left[ \begin{array}{c}
        C_{0,n} \\
        C_{M-1,n}
      \end{array}
  \right]
\]
```

I want to put an equation number at the end of this equation. But only way I know how to do that is to put this whole equation in `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` which gives an error. The error is

> Bad math environment delimiter

When I delete `\[` and `\]` from the start and end of my equation, I no longer get an error. My question is that why am I getting this error just by moving an equation in `\begin` and `\end`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add some line breaks in your code. In its present form, it's not very readable, and horizontal scrolling is painful.

Comment: @Mico: I think your comment actually answers the OP's question. I was too quick to answer before the OP finished editing the question `:)` I'm deleting mine now. As for your question: No, `\tag{...}` doesn't cause duplicate numbering in `equation`-like environments. But it simply *replaces* the numbers that would've been given by those environments.

Comment: @KevinC - Thanks! I've (re)posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The LaTeX macros `\begin{equation}` and `\[` both *initiate* a display-math group, and the macros `\end{equation}` and `\]` both terminate a display-math group. (In addition, the `equation` environment provides a method for numbering the equations, whereas `\[ ... \]` does not.) The LaTeX macros `\begin{equation}` and `\[` are designed purposefully so as not to let users open a display-math group twice; this is why you're getting the error message "Bad math environment delimiter" when LaTeX encounters `\[` after having processed `\begin{equation}`.

The upshot: Use one or the other method for setting up a display-math group, but don't use both simultaneously.

For a more-detailed discussion of how various LaTeX displaymath environments are set up, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/5001) to the question "What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?" Shameless self-citation alert!

Answer (score 3):

I can't improve @Mico 's correct accepted answer to the question you asked, but can suggest that you use a `bmatrix` environment instead of hard coding the brackets and the arrays. You save typing, improve readability, and minimize fiddling:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    v^{0}_{n} \\
    v^{K-1}_{n}
\end{bmatrix} =
    -\frac{1}{C_{ref}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
     V^{0}_{0,n} & \cdots & V^{0}_{M-1,m} \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        V^{K-1}_{0,n} & \cdots &  V^{K-1}_{M-1,n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        C_{0,n} \\
        C_{M-1,n}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the suggested thread when looking up the `Bad math environment delimiter` error on Google, let me add an additional fix. The gist is this: the reverse order of Mico's answer is also true, namely that if you are inside a math environment, `\begin{equation}`, `\begin{align}` etc ... don't work.

There are three related errors you might encounter: `Bad math environment delimiter`, `Missing \endgroup inserted` and `\begin{align} allowed only in paragraph mode`, varying depending on whether you have `mathtools` loaded or not and which math environment you're opening.

In my case, I had loaded `mathtools` and had accidentally forgotten a closing `$` in a paragraph some lines above a `begin{equation}`, causing LaTeX to stay in math mode. MWE of my situation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % Without this loaded, you get "Missing \endgroup" i.o. "Bad math".

\begin{document}

$\zeta(s) is the Riemann zeta function. Oops, forgot a dollar sign there.
Some more sample text.
I, the unsuspecting author, will now attempt to enter a math environment.
\begin{equation}  % If this is align, you get "allowed only in paragraph mode".
    \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}
\end{equation}
The compiler did not like that.

\end{document}
```