# Align and Center equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the following equations . I just want to center them , such that the equality '= ' signs are one below the other. I tried \begin{align} but, that pushes them all to the left of the page.

```
\newcommand{\nrm}[1]{\left \lVert {#1} \right \rVert}

$$ \nrm{e} ^2 _{L_2(I)} = \langle e,e \rangle_{L_2(I)} $$
$$ = \langle e, -\phi '' \rangle_{L_2(I)} $$
$$ = \langle e' ,\phi ' \rangle_{L_2(I)} $$
$$ = \langle e ,\phi  \rangle_{a} $$
```

How do I do it?

Comment: See the postings [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between $$, \\[, align, equation and displaymath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) for reasons for ***not*** using `$$` in your LaTeX documents.

Comment: [Welcome](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `align` environment, lines are centred around the `&` character. Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\nrm}[1]{\left \lVert {#1} \right \rVert}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \nrm{e} ^2 _{L_2(I)} &= \langle e,e \rangle_{L_2(I)} \\
  &= \langle e, -\phi '' \rangle_{L_2(I)} \\
  &= \langle e' ,\phi ' \rangle_{L_2(I)} \\
  &= \langle e ,\phi  \rangle_{a} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The `align*` environment is used to avoid equation numbering; if you want this, remove the asterisks.

Comment: Yeah, This works, Great!!. But it removes the equation number.

Comment: @ssk: The code snippet you posted doesn't produce equation numbers either. If you need equation numbers, it's helpful to state it explicitly in the posting. (Hint: use `align` instead of `align*`.)

Comment: remove the `*` and you get the number back :) If you also add the line breaks be sure to disable the numbering for some lines using `\nonumber`

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I would do it using the powerful [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\inner}{\langle}{\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \norm{e}_{L_{2}(I)}^{2}
  &= \inner{e, e}_{L_{2}(I)}\\
  &= \inner{e, -\phi''}_{L_{2}(I)}\\
  &= \inner{e', \phi'}_{L_{2}(I)}\\
  &= \inner{e, \phi}_{a}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The point of using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` to define the delimiter macros `\norm` and `\inner` is that you will get an automatic scaling by using the starred versions of the macros (and the code syntax in nice and clean).