# How do I align these equations?

Tags: align

```
$\frac{dP}{dr}=\frac{-\Big(P+\rho (P)c^2 \Big)} {2} \frac {d\nu} {dr}\]$\\
\newline
$$\Rightarrow d\nu = \frac {-2dP} {P+\rho (P) c^2}$$\\
\bigskip \newline
$$ \nu (r) = - \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} + \nu (r_b)$$
\newline
\newline
\newline
$$ e^{\nu(r)} &= e^{\nu(r_b) -  \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} }$$
\newline


$$ e^ {\nu (r)}= e^{\nu(r_b)} exp \Big[-\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} \Big]$$
```

I am New to Latex so my codes look trivial , can you please align these equations for me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the `align*` environment (provided by the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package), one can group the five equations and align them horizontally. You didn't say *how* they should be aligned, so I've assumed they ought to be aligned on the respective `=` symbols.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{dP}{dr}&=\frac{-\bigl(P+\rho (P)c^2 \bigr)} {2} 
\frac {d\nu} {dr}\\
\Rightarrow d\nu &= \frac {-2dP} {P+\rho (P) c^2} \\
\nu (r) &= - \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} + \nu (r_b)\\
e^{\nu(r)} &= \exp\biggl[\nu(r_b) -  \int_{0}^{P(r)} 
              \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} \biggr]\\
e^ {\nu (r)}&= e^{\nu(r_b)} \exp \biggl[-\int_{0}^{P(r)} 
\frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} \biggr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The biggest change, obviously, is the use of the `align*` environment and the elimination of all `\newline` instructions. Some other changes: Use of `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` in the first line (you were using `\Big(` and `\Big)`); use of `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` in the last two lines; and, use of `\exp` in the final two lines (note that the "exp" string is set in upright letters).

See also the posting [What are the differences between $$, [, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) for a discussion of how these display-math environments differ.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{dP}{dr}=\frac{-\left(P+\rho (P)c^2 \right)}{2} \frac {d\nu}{dr}\Rightarrow d\nu &= \frac {-2dP} {P+\rho (P) c^2}\\
\nu (r) &= \nu (r_b)- \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2}  \\
e^{\nu(r)} &= e^{\nu(r_b) - \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} }\\
e^ {\nu (r)}&= e^{\nu(r_b)} \exp \left(-\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac {2dP}{P+\rho (P) c^2} \right)\end{align*}
```

Comment: Thank you, it would have been better if the "implies" that equation starts from line 2, instead of from right of the first equation. can You do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*\ABLD{\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]&&}
\newcommand*\diffOp{\mathop{}\!\mathit{d}}
\newcommand*\diff[2]{\frac{\diffOp #1}{\diffOp #2}} % can be made more flexible but no need in this case

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  && \diff{P}{r}
  &= \frac{-(P + \rho(P)c^{2})}{2}\diff{\nu}{r}\\
  \ABLD
  \diffOp \nu
  &= \frac{-2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\\
  \ABLD
  \nu(r)
  &= -\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}} + \nu(r_{b})\\
  \ABLD
  e^{\nu(r)}
  &= \exp{\mkern -8mu}\left[\nu(r_{b}) - \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\right]\\
  \ABLD
  e^{\nu(r)}
  &= e^{\nu(r_{b})} \exp{\mkern -8mu}\left[-\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\right]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

or maybe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*\ABLD{\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]&&}
\newcommand*\diffOp{\mathop{}\!\mathit{d}}
\newcommand*\diff[2]{\frac{\diffOp #1}{\diffOp #2}} % can be made more flexible but no need in this case

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  && \diff{P}{r}
  &= \frac{-(P + \rho(P)c^{2})}{2}\diff{\nu}{r}\\
  \ABLD
  \diffOp \nu
  &= \frac{-2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\\
  \ABLD
  \nu(r)
  &= -\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}} + \nu(r_{b})\\
  \ABLD
  e^{\nu(r)}
  &= \exp{\mkern -8mu}\left[\nu(r_{b}) - \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\right]{\mkern -6mu}
   = e^{\nu(r_{b})} \exp{\mkern -8mu}\left[-\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\right]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

or maybe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*\ABLD{\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]&&}
\newcommand*\diffOp{\mathop{}\!\mathit{d}}
\newcommand*\diff[2]{\frac{\diffOp #1}{\diffOp #2}} % can be made more flexible but no need in this case

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  && \diff{P}{r}
  &= \frac{-(P + \rho(P)c^{2})}{2}\diff{\nu}{r}\\
  \ABLD
  \diffOp \nu
  &= \frac{-2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\\
  \ABLD
  \nu(r)
  &= -\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}} + \nu(r_{b})\\
  \ABLD
  e^{\nu(r)}
  &= \exp{\mkern -4mu}\biggl[\nu(r_{b}) - \int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\biggr]{\mkern -4mu}\\
  &&&= e^{\nu(r_{b})} \exp{\mkern -4mu}\biggl[-\int_{0}^{P(r)} \frac{2\diffOp P}{P + \rho(P)c^{2}}\biggr]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

if you want smaller brackets and alignment of the last two `=`s.

P.S. I would probably choose the last version.