# How to implement this symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I wanted to do the sigma enclosures in the below shown equation correctly. Actually this is also expectation symbol, right? I don't know it's name.

[image]

Comment: You mean `\langle, \rangle`?

Comment: @percusse: Yes. Please put it in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ExpValue{\langle}{\rangle}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathit{d}}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \ExpValue*{\sigma_{N}^{2}}
  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \diff\sigma P(\sigma)\sigma^{2}
  \simeq \delta_{k}\sum_{i = 1}^{k} P(\sigma_{k})\sigma_{k}^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that with the starred version of `\ExpValue`, ther delimiters will scale automatically.

P.S. Are you sure that `\simeq` shouldn't be `\approx`? (I'm not sure...)

Answer (score 2):

Reproduced equation:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\[
\langle\sigma_{N}^{2}\rangle =
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\sigma P(\sigma)\sigma^{2} \simeq 
    \delta_{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k} P(\sigma_{k})\sigma_{k}^{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nowadays, it is [generally preferred to use  `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/35864).

Comment: Please do not use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate display-math mode. For more information, see the postings [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Answer (score 2):

If you are typing lot of physics, then you may consider using `physics` package. It provides lot of goodies including `\expval`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
\[
 \expval{\sigma_{N}^{2}} =
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\sigma P(\sigma)\sigma^{2} \simeq
    \delta_{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k} P(\sigma_{k})\sigma_{k}^{2}
\]
\[
 \expval{A}{\Psi} \quad \ev{A}{\Psi}  \quad 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]