# Create my own symbols such as Bigotimes

Tags: symbols

I am using the symbol `$\Box$` as a binary operator and would like to create a unary operator symbol starting from that. My goal is to have a symbol that behaves like `$\Bigotimes$` compared to `$\otimes$`, for example.

How can I do that? (I know that I can resize the symbol, for example right now I am using `$\mathop{\text{\Huge $\Box$} \text{\normalsize}}$`, but this has the disadvantage of not scaling properly in `$...$` vs. `$$...$$` environments, and it is also not positioned properly in the vertical direction).

Many thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Furthermore [What are the differences between $$, \\[, align, equation and display math?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/4918) seems to be worth a look regarding the use of `$$` ;-)

Comment: Yes, indeed the question linked by Andrew contains the answer. Sorry, I did not find that question. Thanks again!