# Can I use the \tag command without using \begin{equation}?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I am currently getting into LaTeX, mainly for writing texts with formulas. I have already some experience writing in latex from other SE sites such as Physics or Mathematics. Now I started learning writing LaTeX in a dedicated software (I use TeXstudio, but this probably won't be relevant).

I noted that I cannot use the \tag command when using equations with $$...$$. For example, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $$a=b\tag{1}$$
\end{document}
```

outputs "a=b" and not "a=b (1)". I also get a error code:

> Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here. $$a=b\tag

After some more experimenting, I found that the only (?) way to use the \tag command is by using an equation workspace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        a=b\tag{1}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which outputs the correct result

[image]

Using the equation workspace, you get a default number tag, but this way, you can change it to whatever value you'd like to.

So I have two questions:

1. *Why* is it not possible to add a tag when using equations with $$...$$ or $...$?
2. Is there any workaround? Using an equation environment isn't much of an issue, but I sometimes find the "$" method more comfortable

Comment: You might want to take a look at [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/134144)

Comment: Instead of using `$$`...`$$`, use ``\[``...``\]`` that allows you to use `\tag`.

Comment: `$$` should never be used in latex whether or not you use `\tag`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle after reading the various linked questions, I probably will never do again :) I was used to using `$$` from the SE version of Latex and thought that it was "normal"

Comment: note the latex-like rendering on the stackexchanege sites is MathJax (Javascript) and doesn't actually use tex at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\show\tag
\end{document}
```

you'll see

```
> \tag=macro:
->\invalid@tag {\string \tag \space not allowed here}.
l.4 \show\tag
```

The macro `\tag` is defined by `amsmath`, and its "normal" definition is to yield an error. Only when entering one of the `amsmath` math environments the macro `\tag` is redefined to do what it should do. For example, the expansion of `\begin{equation}`, `\begin{equation*}`, and `\[` involve the macro `\mathdisplay`, whose definition contains the line

```
\let\tag\tag@in@display
```

Similarly, `align`, `flalign`, `gather`, and `multline` result in

```
\let\tag\tag@in@align
```

Since these `\let` assignments happen in a group, the redefinition of `\tag` is local to the current environment, and upon exiting it `\tag` resumes its normal definition (yielding an error).

This explains your "why" issue: when you use `$$` none of the above `\let` is executed, and `\tag` yields an error.

Is there a workaround? There might be. You could do as described in [Defining `$$$ $$$` to align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215029/82917).

Don't. Ever. Please read [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$?`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917) and then forget the previous paragraph.

If you want to give a manual `\tag` to a single-line equation, use `\[...\]`. It involves the same amount of strokes as `$$...$$`. Admittedly, the German keyboard layout does not make this easy; that's why I have a qwerty keyboard even if I live in Germany `:-)`