# Aligning long set of equations

Tags: equations

I'm trying to make a big series of equation equalities in LaTeX, however, my equation just keeps going on out of the page width. Here is what I have:

```
$$
TCU_{1,2}(y_1,y_2)=\frac{25}{4y_1}+\frac{125}{120-y_1} =\frac{25(120-y_1)}{(4y_1)(120-y_1)}+\frac{125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)} \\ =\frac{25(120-y_1)+125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}=\frac{3000+475y_1}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}
$$
```

I need it to align beneath each other, how do I do this? I only use the amsmath package. and an article documentclass.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8):

Use `split` inside `equation*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
TCU_{1,2}(y_1,y_2)&=\frac{25}{4y_1}+\frac{125}{120-y_1} \\
&=\frac{25(120-y_1)}{(4y_1)(120-y_1)}+\frac{125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)} \\ 
&=\frac{25(120-y_1)+125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}\\
&=\frac{3000+475y_1}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to number the equation, use the `equation` environment instead of `equation*`.

Also, don-t use `$$`..`$$` in LaTeX. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/27635) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me the difference between \begin{equation} and $$? I haven't had to use \begin{equation} before.

Comment: @user70257 Take a look at the link in my answer.

Comment: @user70257 - Do also check out the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001).

Comment: @user70257 And remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved, if it solved your problem. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: I sugggest you to read for example Math mode (http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) or similar document about formating math.

Comment: I forgot to log into my account to ask the question and now I logged out of the guest account so is there still a way to mark it as solved? Thanks a lot for those links as well!

Comment: @Pim -- take a look at [Merge user accounts](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1054/579)

Comment: @Pim Use http://tex.stackexchange.com/contact to contact the StackExchange staff: they can merge your accounts together.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a left-aligned stack.  The interline gap is settable with `\setstackgap{S}{gap-size}`.  The default Shortstack gap is 3pt, which seems to small for my taste in this situation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}% SETS GAP BETWEEN STACK LINES
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
TCU_{1,2}(y_1,y_2)\Shortunderstack[l]{
  {}=\dfrac{25}{4y_1}+\dfrac{125}{120-y_1} \\
  {}=\dfrac{25(120-y_1)}{(4y_1)(120-y_1)}+\dfrac{125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)} \\ 
  {}=\dfrac{25(120-y_1)+125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}\\
  {}=\dfrac{3000+475y_1}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The identical result could be obtained with a TABstack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{8pt}% SETS GAP BETWEEN STACK LINES
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\alignShortunderstack{%
TCU_{1,2}(y_1,y_2)
  =&\dfrac{25}{4y_1}+\dfrac{125}{120-y_1} \\
  =&\dfrac{25(120-y_1)}{(4y_1)(120-y_1)}+\dfrac{125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)} \\ 
  =&\dfrac{25(120-y_1)+125(4y_1)}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}\\
  =&\dfrac{3000+475y_1}{(120-y_1)(4y_1)}
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I said it before, but I will say it again: the interface for that package is awful (just my opinion, don't worry), I think you should think about a better interface (proably with key-value optional arguments). It would gain usability and users.

Comment: @Manuel I appreciate your input.

Comment: Rereading, it may seem like “bad words”, I meant no “aggression”; while I really think your packages are useful, they lack of an acceptable interface.

Comment: @Manuel I take it in the spirit in which it was intended, namely constructive criticism.  Given lots of free time, I would move upon it, but that commodity has been in relatively short supply of late.