# How we fix (La)TeX math coding to be left aligned

Tags: math-mode

In display math (employing `$$...$$`) content normally gets aligned centered. But, I need it to be left aligned. Any suggestions?

#### Example

```
$$f(x) = \frac{{{{\sin }^2}x{\mkern 1mu} \cos x}}{{\sin x + \cos x}} -
         \frac{1}{4}\tan (\frac{\pi }{4} - x){\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} 
         \forall {\mkern 1mu} x \in R - \{ n\pi  - \frac{\pi }{4}\} ,n \in I$$
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632628/left-align-block-of-equations

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you please clarify what you are exactly looking for? It's hard to tell right now as the wrong grammar (nothing personal!) of your post obscures the acutal meaning.

Comment: @Ruben: or the obtusal meaning?

Comment: Thanks Ruben, In this equation generally shows center but i need an left align

Comment: See: [Why is ```\[ … \]``` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/16967)

Comment: Here we are using this $$ format

Comment: @Rajesh You should reword your question so it's clear what you are looking for, and, in case you are using plainTeX or any other format (like LaTeX), explicitly say so.

Comment: I would'nt go that far, @Bernard ...

Comment: Maybe have a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math

Comment: @Ruben `! Missing [sic] inserted`
`I would'nt` `go that far  <to be read again>`

Comment: @Manuel -- can't be using plain tex.  `\frac` is a latex construct.

Answer (score 2):

Is `fleqn` what you are looking for? (By the way, I rewrote the code in a more clear way, at least to me)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % Just for this example (the \kant command)

\begin{document}
\kant*[1]
\[
  f(x) = \frac{\sin^2 x \cos x}{\sin x + \cos x}
         - \frac{1}{4} \tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{4} - x\Bigr) 
  \quad
  \forall x \in R \setminus \Bigl\{ n\pi - \frac{\pi}{4} \Bigr\}, \ n \in I
\]
\kant*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but we are using $$...$$ is there any possibilities for in this coding format

Comment: See [Heiko's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247172/how-we-fix-latex-math-coding-left-align/247175#comment587855_247172).

Comment: @Rajesh - If, for some reason, you're unable or unwilling to replace `$$` with `\[` and `\]`, and if you're able to run LuaLaTeX, you may want to look into the answer given to the posting [Can I get $$…$$ to behave like \\[…\\]?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240139/5001)

Comment: @Rajesh `$$` is a syntax error, you should fix that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `$$`, it's plain-TeX syntax and does not have the flexibility, for example, to move the equations automatically to the left.
2. Don't use `$$`, ...
3. Don't use `$$`, ...

---

The formatting of `$$` is hard-coded in TeX, thus to change its behavior for automatic left-aligning, the source code of TeX needs to be changed.

With extra TeX code, also `$$...$$` can be left aligned, but then it's cleaner to use the correct markup in the first place, where options like `fleqn` just work.

A. Package `varwidth`. Environment `varwidth` puts its contents into a `minipage` unpacks it and shrinks the contents to the maximal needed width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[101]

\noindent
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$$
  f(x) = \frac{\sin^2x \, \cos x}{\sin x + \cos x} -
  \frac{1}{4}\tan (\frac{\pi }{4} - x)
  \quad\forall x \in\mathds{R}
  \setminus \left\{ n\pi - \frac{\pi}{4}, n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \right\}, n \in \mathds{I}
$$
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result <code>varwidth</code>]

The vertical spacing needs some manual fixing.

B. If the equation starts with a glue, then TeX respects this glue setting assuming the user knows, what he is using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[101]
$$
  \hspace{0pt minus \linewidth}
  f(x) = \frac{\sin^2x \, \cos x}{\sin x + \cos x} -
  \frac{1}{4}\tan (\frac{\pi }{4} - x)
  \quad\forall x \in\mathds{R}
  \setminus \left\{ n\pi - \frac{\pi}{4}, n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \right\}, n \in \mathds{I}
  \hspace{\linewidth minus -1fil}
$$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result glue]

The trick is based on the second `\hspace` with `\linewidth`, which forces an overfull equation. Then TeX will contribute the shrink parts, moving to the left in the first `\hspace` and filling the right with `minus -1fil` of the second `\hspace`.