# Example in which `$$...$$` gets wrong spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, amsmath

The use of `\[...\]` vs. `$$...$$` is discussed in [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/) and [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492).

It seems like `\[...\]` has benefits in some uncommon uses cases (`leqno` and `\qedhere`), but the main reason to use it is, according to most answerers, spacing issues.

However, in the answers I only see examples of how `\[...\]` leads to *worse* spacing without `amsmath`.

Could someone provide a minimal example of an incorrect spacing produced by `$$...$$`, which is fixed by switching to `\[...\]` and `amsmath`?

If you wish, you can start by modifying the following M(non-)WE (which, as it is, shows no difference between the two variants, at least on my machine with Texlive 2015). The `rule`s are `\smash`ed, so they should take up no space, and they are there only to show that the spacing above and below the equation is exactly the same (idea taken from jfbu's answers to the two above-cited questions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Wrong spacing:\hrulefill\par
$$
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule[-4ex]{.4pt}{9.5ex}}
$$
\hrulefill\par

Correct spacing:\hrulefill\par
\[
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule[-4ex]{.4pt}{9.5ex}}
\]
\hrulefill\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't David's answer there cover it? That `\[ \]` does better than `$$ $$` without `amsmath` but that `\[ \]` plus `amsmath` is better still? Is there disagreement about which variation has better spacing or...?

Comment: @cfr but I see no example on David's answer showing the problem with spacing using `$$...$$`.

Comment: @cfr Exactly like Gonzalo said. The only MWE is in [jfbu's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163205/1371), but it simply shows the bug in `\[...\]` without `amsmath`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think using `\hrulefill` (or `\hrule`) creates a misleading impression here, as it places its output *below* the baselines -- not where one would usually expect to find text. (Aside: When was the last time you saw a real document that had displayed equations bounded above and below by `\hrule`s?)  I'd rather use lines of dummy text above and below the equations to assess the vertical spacing issues associated with various ways of creating displayed equations.

Below is a slightly modified version of the MWE I posted in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/5001) to one of the two postings you provided a link to. Both displayed equations have a blank line above them, forcing them to start in TeX's "vertical mode". How do the two methods handle this sub-optimal situation? The first displayed equation is generated with `\[ ... \]`, and it is well centered. In contrast, the second displayed equation, which is generated with `$$ ... $$`, is not centered properly.

I hope this example addresses your request,

> Could someone provide a minimal example of an incorrect spacing produced by `$$...$$`, which is fixed by switching to `\[...\]`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{1in} % use a very narrow measure for this example
\begin{document}
\noindent
some words some

\[ u=vwxz\]
some words some 

$$u=vwxz$$
some words some
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. What I find confusing, though, is that if one adds `\usepackage{amsmath}`, then both versions look like the second one. So this means that `amsmath` actually makes `\[...\]` behave *worse*? Or maybe there is some reason why the second kind of spacing (uneven) is considered better?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - The `amsmath` package redefines `\[` and `\]` to behave like `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}`, respectively. Importantly, the `\nointerlineskip` instruction that's provided in the LaTeX kernel definition of `\[` is *not* included in the `amsmath` definition of `\begin{equation*}`. (I have truly no idea why it was omitted.) The wisdom of the often-found exhortation not to have displayed equations start a paragraph manifests itself once again when one uses the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Mico -- I think your comment here is the key to the answer of the technical part of this question. (The aesthetic question may have a different answer, if it is answerable at all.)

Comment: @jon - I meant to challenge the notion, expressed by the OP, that "... I only see examples of how `\[...\]` leads to worse spacing without `amsmath`." I hope my answer, which deliberately did not load the `amsmath` package, provides such a challenge.

Comment: I appreciate a lot your answer, but I must say this leaves me even more confused as to what the best practice is (apart from "never start paragraphs with an equation").

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - For LaTeX documents, I see some upsides and no downsides in using `\[ ... `]` instead of `$$ ... $$` for unnumbered, single-line equations.

Comment: @Mico If I am not missing anything, [jvbu's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163205/1371) in one of the linked question shows a spacing issue using `\[...\]` without amsmath. Your answer shows a spacing issue when using `$$...$$`, as well as `\[...\]` with amsmath. So it seems like each alternative has some downsides.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - On jfbu's answer: egreg pointed out in a comment that it's not correct to create consecutive displayed equations the way jfbu does. Any tool can be abused -- is the subsequent disappointing performance the tool's fault, or should the user be blamed for the abusive behavior? (I strongly tend toward the latter view.) Hence, I don't think it can be said that jfbu established a meaningful weakness of  `\[ ... \]`-without-`amsmath` (relative to the plain-TeX `$$ ... $$` method).

Comment: @Mico I understand, this view makes sense, thanks. So using `\[...\]` is indeed the best practice, but using `amsmath` reintroduces the wrong spacing behaviour.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - AFAICT, the incorrect spacing of `\[...\]` with `amsmath` loaded occurs only if the displayed equation starts a paragraph. As David Carlisle has noted in the meantime in an answer of his own, best practice is definitely *not* to start a paragraph with a displayed equation, under any circumstance.

Answer (score 10):

The main reason for using `\[` is not for spacing issues. It is for better error checking and support for `fleqn`.

The behaviour of `\[` v amsmath-`\[` v `$$` at the start of a paragraph is really a minor things as in no cases should a math display ever start a paragraph and although there are minor differences in error recovery the spacing in all cases varies from poor to awful, so should never occur in a real document.