# Amsmath Cases syntax

Tags: amsmath, cases

The amsmath `cases` environment seems to require being placed within `\[...\]`. What is that syntax? Amsmath documentation does not include these square brackets, yet cases won't compile without them.

Comment: I don't understand you :S the `cases` environment *must* appear in math mode. Math mode may be entered by `$ ... $` or `\( ... \)` for in-line maths and `\[ ... \]` for displayed maths. There are also environments, such as `equation` and `flalign*` which automatically put you in math mode as well, but one way or another, you *must* be in math mode. The syntax for entering displaymath mode, though, is just `\[ ... \]`

Comment: `cases` is math.  i believe you mean that this environment needs to be put inside `\[ ... \]`, not just ordinary braces. yes, that is true.  these are not `\textbackslash`, but actual backslashes, and the `\[ ... \]` is a pair of commands that indicates display math with no equation number.  this is equivalent to `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`  (welcome, by the way.)

Comment: you're correct that the `amsmath` documentation doesn't spell out the meaning or use of `\[ ... \]`.  i've added that to the bugs list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - As `\[` and `\]` are set up in the LaTeX kernel, it's probably not necessary to explain in any detail what these instructions are in the user guide of the `amsmath` package. I think it may suffice to state explicitly in the user guide that the `cases` environment must be embedded in a math environment -- preferably a display-math environment, right? -- and mention a couple of examples of numbered and unnumbered display-math environments.

Comment: @Mico -- the "fix" i had in mind is simply to state that `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` is equivalent to `\[ ... \]`.  i would have assumed it to be obvious that any new command or environment described in the `amsmath` documentation would by necessity have to be within a math environment, but perhaps i'd better add that too.  (kind of like the warning on a coffee cup. "the contents may be hot", but ...)

Answer (score 5):

The amsmath `cases` environment *must* be used in math mode. While not absolutely mandatory, `cases` environments are generally used in display-style math mode. (The other math mode in TeX is frequently called inline-style.) The Plain-TeX method of initiating and terminating display-style math mode -- `$$ ... $$` -- should not be used in LaTeX; instead, one should use `\[ ... \]` to get an *unnumbered* display-style math environment. Of course, `cases` environments may be used in *numbered* `equation` environments as well.

For more on the differences between  `$$ ... $$` and `\[ ... \]`, see the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)