# Adding a equation number to a matrix

Tags: equations, numbering

I do have a matrix but I can't add a reference number for it as shown in read in the photo below .. any help?

```
\[
  A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 \\
    0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.3 \\
    0.3 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.3 \\
    0.0 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\label{e1}
```

[image]

Comment: This is because you use `\[ ... \]` to create the math environment. Replace that by `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` to get a tagged equation. You can find more information on the math environments and their difference in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath)

Comment: Consider reading up on some material in [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5764)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use an `equation`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

See~\eqref{eq:myeqn} below.
\begin{equation}
  A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 \\
    0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.3 \\
    0.3 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.3 \\
    0.0 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4
  \end{pmatrix}
  \label{eq:myeqn}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```