# Begin{equation} works better with \ than $$

Tags: equations

I am relatively new to LateX, and am a bit confused with the `\begin{equation}` command. I use `$$...$$` to enter the math mode in a new environment. However, I find that when I combine `$$..$$` with `\begin{equation}`, the equation is not centered. However, for some reason, `\begin{equation}` seems to work with the ..\ method of writing equations better. Is there any reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). You should never use `$$` and surely not `$$\begin{equation}...\end{equation}$$`: just `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Comment: Another must-read posting: [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Comment: Out of curiosity: how does a new user end up using `$$`?

Comment: I use $$ on other stack exchange websites.

Comment: @ChinG: That's completely different. On website you're using MathJax, and it's display-math format usage is `$$`...`$$`.

Comment: @Werner actually mathjax uses `\[` by default as well:-)

Comment: what do you mean by `\ ` method?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I almost said "awesome sauce"...