# Equation and italics

Tags: equations, italic

How do I write the equation

```
{x|A'x=b'}
```

in LaTeX and make it italic?
I have tried following code:

```
 \textit{{$$x|$$A'x=b$'}}
```

but it did not work. The dollar signs are in wrong places.

Comment: I recommend looking at a getting started guide to LaTeX. I don't know where to begin explaining, but the correct code is `\[ \{x \mid A'x=b'\}  \]` or similar.

Comment: For more information on why one shouldn't use `$$` in LaTeX documents, see the postings [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to manually create a math environment, by using `\textit`. For inline math use `$` and use `$$` or an environment for interline math.
`$\{x'\mid A'x=b'\}$`

The curly braces have to be set by `\{`, since a single brace is a grouping token in LaTeX, so it will be ignored in the output.

Comment: Please **don't** suggest to use `$$` in conjunction with `LaTeX`. `\[...\]` is the correct form for `LaTeX`, not `$$...$$`