# Why does a line break before align environment create extra space, while itemize does not?

Tags: spacing, align, itemize

As you can see in the example below, the `itemize` environment is the same whether or not there is a line break before the `\begin{itemize}`. However, the `align` environment has significantly more space if one puts in a line break. First, why is this the case? Second, is there a way to make the `align` environment behave like `itemize` -- or is there an alternative package to `align` with the same functionality that I could use?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Here are some items without a line break:
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

Here are some items with a line break:

\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

Here is an equation without a line break:
\begin{align}
X = 2
\end{align}

Here is an equation with a line break

\begin{align}
X = 2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For some general information on the subject of differences in whitespace amounts above and below various displayed math groups, see [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect: `itemize` *does* behave differently if preceded by a blank line. Here's a proof:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\partopsep}{40pt} % very large value to emphasize the effect

\begin{document}
Here are some items without a line break:
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

Here are some items with a line break:

\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

Here is an equation without a line break:
\begin{align}
X = 2
\end{align}

Here is an equation with a line break

\begin{align}
X = 2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The effect is emphasized by giving a very large value to `\partopsep`, which is the parameter storing the amount of vertical space that's added to `\topsep` before and after a list environment (`itemize`, `enumerate` or `description`). Its default value in the standard classes is `2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt`, so quite small but noticeable.

On the other hand, LaTeX and `amsmath` start from the assumption that a math display should never start a paragraph. It's a consequence of the implementation that doing so adds an empty line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer. *Please do not up-vote.*)

Your assertion that

> the `itemize` environment is the same whether or not there is a line break before the `\begin{itemize}`

isn't quite correct, as the following example demonstrates. It uses a two-column document layout. Observe that the two `\hrule`s don't quite line up. (Incidentally, I interpreted your term "line break" as "blank line".)

[image]

The difference is quite obviously not as glaring as with the `align` case, but it's definitely non-zero.

It's also worth noting that the two `\hrule`s do line up perfectly *if* the line that precedes the `itemize` environment is terminated with an explicit `\par` statement.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\verb+itemize+ environment not preceded by a blank line
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\hrule

\newpage% force a column break
\verb+itemize+ environment preceded by a blank line

\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: good demonstration.  to note the obvious, a blank line is interpreted by latex as `\par`, so it's no surprise that those behave identically.