# How to draw matrix with dots?

Tags: matrices

How can I draw a matrix with dots in tex like the one shown below:

[image: matrix]

Comment: `\dots` `\vdots` `\ddots` plus `bmatrix` env

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I suggest you load the `amsmath` package, employ its the `bmatrix` ("bracketed matrix") environment, and use `\dots` (or `\ldots`), `\vdots` ("vertical dots"), and `\ddots` ("diagonal dots") as needed.

The following screenshot shows two ways this approach could be employed. The first replicates the matrix shown in the OP's posting. The second shows that this method can be used for square as well as non-square matrices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \\
    a_{K1} &        & a_{KK} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix} 
    b_{11} & \dots  & b_{1M}\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    b_{K1} & \dots  & b_{KM} 
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the usage of \[ and \] before and after the matrix definition?

Comment: @Meysam  -- `\[` is LaTeX code to initiate an unnumbered display-math environment, and `\]` is LaTeX code to terminate this environment. Please check out the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath?`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) for more information on the subject of TeX and LaTeX display-math environments.

Comment: `\cdots` might be more appropriate than `\dots`, depending what look exactly you're going for.

Comment: @TheZachMan - As a typographic ellipsis, `\cdots` is generally used only as the connector between (explicit or implicit) binary operators. E.g., `a_1+a_2+\cdots+c_n`, or `b_1 b_2 \cdots b_T`. Plus, there's the multIple integration case: `\int\int\cdots\int`. I don't think that that's the impression one wants to create for "gaps" in a row of a matrix. Hence, I'm comfortable with using `\dots` (or `\ldots`) for the matrices at hand.

Comment: I think it's appropriate since it matches the centering of `\vdots` and `\ddots`, but fair enough.

Comment: @TheZachMan - By your argument, there could *never* be a use case for `\ldots` in a matrix. That can't be quite right, can it?

Answer (score 2):

For information, here is what you can do with `{bNiceMatrix}` with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots/shorten=0.5em}
A = \begin{bNiceMatrix} 
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \Ldots \\
    \Vdots & \Ddots & \\
    a_{K1} &        & a_{KK} 
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{bNiceMatrix} 
    b_{11} & \Ldots  & b_{1M}\\
    \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots\\
    b_{K1} & \Ldots  & b_{KM} 
    \end{bNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]