# How can I assign an equation number to this matrix equation?

Tags: equations, matrices

I want to assign an equation number to the following matrix equation; I want a number in brackets on the right side, after the equation.

```
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

But adding `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` around this throws an error at `\[`. How can I number this matrix equation properly?

Comment: use `equation` _instead_ of `\[ \]` not in addition to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\[` with `\begin{equation}` and `\]` with `\end{equation}`.

A complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For more on `\[... \]`, the `equation` environment, and still other methods for creating displaystyle equations, see [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)