# Inexplicable equation numbering in Beamer

Tags: beamer, equations

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{gather}\label{equation1}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{gather}
    Consider \eqref{equation1}. This is fine.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    But then:
    \begin{gather}\label{equation2}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2\nonumber\\
    r + s + t
    \end{gather}

    \begin{equation}
    x = 2
    \end{equation}

    Equation (2) is referenced as \eqref{equation2}. Why???
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I do not understand why in the last line, \eqref(equation2) shows up as (3) despite clearly being designated as (2). How do I work around this in an efficient manner, particularly since I am going to have to code multiple slides with this sort of thing?

Comment: You explicately said that the second equation will not get a number. This would confuse me as well. Place the label at the end of the `gather` block, not at the beginning.

Comment: Aside: Using `gather` (and `align`) environments for single-line displayed equations constitutes a form of typographic abuse. Use `equation` environments instead. See the posting [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) for more information on this subject.

Comment: Add your `\label` after the *second* equation of your `gather` environment.

Comment: I put the label just inside the \end{gather} tag. It does what I want now. But why was it messing up to begin with? Again, this was not a problem in regular documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amsmath environments `align` and `gather` are intended to typeset multiple equations, so they require putting one `\label{whatever}` per line you want to refer to.

What happens if you put `\label{equation2}` at the line which is marked by `\nonumber` (so, you don't want to number this equation)  is that the label will pick up the previously stepped counter. In this case it's a frame number counter, so your (3) meant the frame number and not the equation number.

Moving he label `\label{equation2}` definition to the second equation in the `gather` environment helps.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{gather}\label{equation1}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{gather}
    Consider \eqref{equation1}. This is fine.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    But then:
    \begin{gather}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2\nonumber\\
    r + s + t\label{equation2}
    \end{gather}

    \begin{equation}
    x = 2
    \end{equation}

    Equation (2) is referenced as \eqref{equation2}. Why???
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good catch, identifying the fact that the unexpected number "3" refers to the frame number and not to the (later) equation number.

Answer (score 6):

You have the `\label` in the wrong place: they need to come *after* the numbered item:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{gather}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2\label{equation1}
    \end{gather}
    Consider \eqref{equation1}. This is fine.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    But then:
    \begin{gather}
    x^2 + y^2 = z^2\nonumber\\
    r + s + t\label{equation2}
    \end{gather}

    \begin{equation}
    x = 2
    \end{equation}

    Equation~(2) is referenced as \eqref{equation2}. Why???
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```