# An issue with tikz theorem formatting

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, theorems

I am new to latex and learning more tools on the fly, by using templates and playing around with parameters and arguments.

So I tried the following tikz construction for boxing a theorem

```
\newcounter{theorem}[chapter] \setcounter{theorem}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}
\newenvironment{theorem}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theorem}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=.5pt]
\node()[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheorem};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=.5pt]
\node()[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheorem:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=5pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}
```

What this does is block out the first couple of letters in the theorem statement. Moreover, it often splits across different pages in an ugly way. I tried tweeking around with the parameters and margins, etc. but to no avail.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here's a sample document you can copy and compile for yourself to see the error first hand.

```
\documentclass[15pt]{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{,tikz-           cd,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,sectsty,url,graphicx,MnSymbol,algorithm,listings,color,appendix,mathrsfs,makeidx}
\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=1.0in,vmargin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeindex

\newcounter{theorem}[chapter] \setcounter{theorem}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}
\newenvironment{theorem}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theorem}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=.5pt]
\node()[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheorem};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=.5pt]
\node()[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheorem:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=5pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\title{
\textbf{Test Document}}
\author{
\Large{Latex n00b}}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\maketitle

\chapter{First Chapter}
So as I mentioned, the tikz theorem box as defined above cuts the first    letter of the theorem statement. It also splits across pages in an ugly way.
\begin{theorem}
For $p$ be a prime,
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$ 
\end{theorem}
It also shows errors when the theorem statement comprises only an equation.
\begin{theorem}
$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}  i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example  [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (including only relevant packages) that still illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code.

Comment: The code does not compile (`! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \end{theorem}`) and is not minimal (many packages loaded which are unrelated to your question). Did you actually test the code that you provide? Probably unrelated, `$$` should not be used anymore. Use `\begin{equation}...` instead. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492 for details.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `\[...\]` is the replacement for `$$...$$` in 2e, as far as I know. Of course, a maths environment is another option, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Note that the `15pt` means `10pt` so you might as well omit it.

Comment: The `theroem` environment is defined with two parameters, `\newenvironment{theorem}[2][]` one optional (empty by default) and another mandatory which is used as a label. You need to always type this mandatory parameter which can be empty: `\begin{theorem}{}`.  Otherwise, the first letter of theorem text is used as label.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, theorem definition starts with:

```
\newenvironment{theorem}[2][]{%
```

which means that the environment will have an initially empty optional parameter and a mandatory one. Therefore, your theorem environments should be:

```
\begin{theorem}{...}  %<--- No optional parameter and one mandatory
theorem contents
\end{theorem}
```

As you don't include the mandatory parameter, fist letters of theorem contents are used as it. As soon as you add `{}` the problem will disappear.

As you say that you're learning LaTeX, may be you cold be interested in [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package wich provides an special library for boxed theorems. Following code shows how reproduce your theorems format with `tcolorbox`.

In this case `\newtcolorbox` declares a theorem environment called `myTheorem` which will have two mandatory arguments, the first one is theorem title and the second a label sufix. The same command also defines a `myTheorem*` environment for unnumbered theorems.

```
\documentclass[15pt]{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{myTheorem}{THEOREM}{%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    colframe=blue!20,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=blue!20,
    coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={sharp corners},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
}{th}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{myTheorem*}{}{}
For $p$ be a prime,
\[a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p\] 
\end{myTheorem*}
\begin{myTheorem}{This is another theorem}{NT}
\[\sum_{i=1}^{n}  i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
\end{myTheorem}

As you can see in Theorem~\ref{th:NT}
\end{document}
```

[image]