# Correct way to typeset 'implies' symbol

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, alignat

I want to generate the following mathematics:
[image: math image]

The code I am using is this (I am using AMS Math):

```
$$
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &&           \sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= r \\
    &\implies&   x^2+y^2        &= r^2
  \end{alignedat}
$$
```

But I don't think that this is the correct way. Is there a better way?

**Also, is the typesetting in the picture wrong? If it is so, then what should be the correct code?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From LaTeX side is nothing wrong (except that you use TeX math delimiters, LaTeX `\[ ...\]` is used.  Regarding math side, this is mater of habits and taste ... And, please, provide complete document, not just code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears the equations should be aligned on the `=` symbols, I suggest you use an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= r \\
    \implies x^2+y^2 &= r^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to start and end (unnumbered) display-math  mode. For more on this topic, please see the postings [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Comment: *Since the equations should be centered* — says who? If you look at the screenshot in the question, the equal signs are aligned, while in the output from your code they are not.

Comment: Just typeset your document and compare with the screenshot in the question :-) I think it's fine to say that the typesetting in the question is wrong or whatever (that would be useful with an explanation), but as it stands, this answer proposes something different from what was asked in the question, with no explanation for the difference, just an assertion.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I have edited the question.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - My apologies -- I had glanced at the OP's screenshot obliquely and not noticed that there was, in fact, an alignment on the = symbols. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Cool, upvoted :-)