# Error "! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter."

Tags: math-mode, errors

> **Edit** by ManuelKuehner
>
> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
> ```

I am confused how to make the below formula in LaTeX:

[image]

I have been trying the below code, but it leads to an error:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
    P(Attack¦Asset)  = \[\frac{\,\ attack,\ asset}\]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got `! LaTeX Error: File `llncs.cls' not found.`. Please tell us which error you are getting.

Comment: Remove `\[` and `\]` from the equation. (And probably you also want to use package `amsmath` and use `\text{...}` for the text parts of the equation.)

Comment: The  `\[` `\]` within equation are superfluous.

Comment: `\frac` needs two arguments but you only provided one, that's an additional error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Here's a starting point.
- `Asset` and `Attack` are words and not variables I guess so I used `\text` from the `amsmath` package (loaded by `mathtools`). Both are famous and standard packages for math stuff.
- You used `\[` and `\]` inside a math environment -- I guess it's just *copy and paste* from somewhere. This was an error. See [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    P(\text{Attack} \mid \text{Asset})  = \frac{P(\text{Attack} \cap \text{Asset})}{P(\text{Asset})}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I didn't know the funny arc symbol so I looked in [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

[image]

Comment: Probably `\mid` would look better than `|`.

Comment: You should address the real error in the question, namely using `\[` and `\]` inside `equation`!

Comment: @Bernard Done :)

Comment: @clemens I am still typing...but yes

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner you post your answers *before* you've finished them? o.O

Comment: @clemens Very often...step by step :)

Comment: You have a "given" instead of "intersection" in the right side of the equation.

Comment: @gusbrs I have to leave now. Feel free to correct/edit my answer.

Comment: Already corrected. By "intersection" I meant "the funny arc symbol".

Answer (score 3):

From the `mathtools` manual mostly....  Note that the spacing is correct everywhere.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens()
\providecommand\given{}
\newcommand\Symbol[1][]{%
    \nonscript\:#1\vert
    \allowbreak
    \nonscript\:
    \mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\condr[1](){\renewcommand\given{\Symbol[\delimsize]}#1}


\begin{document}
\[
\Pr\condr{\text{Attack} \given \text{Asset}} = \frac{ \Pr\parens{ \text{Attack} \cap \text{Asset}} }{\Pr\parens{\text{Asset}}}
\]
\end{document}
```