# how to write this equation in latex A=(a_ij), a_ij=P(si|sj)?

Tags: equations

```
$$A=(a_i j ),           a_ij= Р(s_i ┤| s_j)$$
```

This coding shows result without `P` in equation and I need `P` in equation

Comment: A=(a_ij), a_ij=P(si|sj)

Comment: If I see correctly, in the snippet you posted the P isn't a Latin capital P but a cyrilic P (`D0` `A0`). That won't work out of the box.

Comment: suggest me some coding which gives simmiler output

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `$$` in LaTeX documents to initiate and terminate a displayed equation; use `\[` and `\]` instead. For more information on this subject, please see the postings [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment and '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{P}
\begin{document}
\[
A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{ij}\end{pmatrix}, 
\quad a_{ij}=\Prob(\,s_i\mid s_j\,)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pmatrix` feels a wee bit like an overkill (but you still get your upvote `;-)`)

Comment: @campa - Thanks. :-) I guess the main thing that `pmatrix` does here is to employ `\big` parentheses. Hence, instead of writing `\begin{pmatrix}a_{ij}\end{pmatrix}`, one could also write `\bigl(a_{ij}\bigr)`. The former method is a bit more "LaTeX-y", though, since it a bit higher-level in its setup, i.e., focuses more on *meaning*.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.209 \DeclareMathOperator
                          {\Prob}{P}
?

Comment: @IshaShirbhate - Indeed, the instruction `\DeclareMathOperator` can be used only in the preamble. That's exactly where it's located in the answer I provided. Did you maybe try to place it *after* `\begin{document}`? If so, it's not going to work.