# Make Legendre symbols the same size

Tags: math-mode

I've been having a bit of trouble typesetting (n-th power) Legendre symbols. I've set up the command

```
\newcommand{\Leg}[3][]{\left(\frac{#2}{#3}\right)_{#1}}
```

But, when I type e.g.

```
$$\Leg[3]{\pi}{\theta} = \Leg[3]{\theta}{\pi}$$
```

the symbol on the left is smaller than the one on the right:

[image: img]

I'd be very grateful if someone could suggest a way to make the symbols the same size. (Either a way to set up the `\Leg` command so it always outputs symbols of the same size, or an ad hoc way of adjusting the size each time I use `\Leg` would be great.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Basically you want to abandon `\left` and `\right` in favor of manual size specifications, because you do not want auto-sizing, but manual size (so that both have equal height).

Comment: use `\Bigl(..\Bigr)` and also don't use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you!
@DavidCarlisle is there an alternative to $$ you'd recommend?

Comment: @RobSmith any documented latex math environment! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can (and should) use `\genfrac`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\genlegendre}[4]{%
  \genfrac{(}{)}{}{#1}{#3}{#4}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else_{\!#2}\fi
}
\newcommand{\legendre}[3][]{\genlegendre{}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\dlegendre}[3][]{\genlegendre{0}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\tlegendre}[3][]{\genlegendre{1}{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

We can use the Legendre symbol $\legendre{\pi}{\theta}$
\[
\legendre[3]{\pi}{\theta} = \legendre[3]{\theta}{\pi}
\]
We can also choose the size
\[
\frac{\dlegendre[2]{\pi}{\theta}+1}{3}
\]
\end{document}
```

The command `\legendre`, `\dlegendre` and `\tlegendre` act the same as `\frac`, `\dfrac` and `\tfrac`.

[image]

The `\genfrac` command takes six arguments:

1. left delimiter (if empty, no delimiter);
2. right delimiter (if empty, no delimiter);
3. the thickness of the fraction line (if empty, standard thickness);
4. the math style to use (if empty, use the current style); styles are denoted by 0 (display style), 1 (text style), 2 (script style), 3 (scriptscript style);
5. the numerator;
6. the denominator.

Thus we get `\legendre` from `\genlegendre` by passing nothing as fourth argument to `\genfrac`, `\dlegendre` by passing `0`.

The `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` trick is for avoiding an empty subscript that would generate `\scriptspace` nonetheless.

Comment: To make the use of `\genfrac` more understandable, you could use `\genfrac{(}{)}...` instead of `\genfrac()...`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Done; added also some information about `\genfrac`.

Answer (score 15):

A solution with `\mathstrut` and the `mleftright` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright} 
\newcommand{\Leg}[3][]{\mleft(\frac{#2\mathstrut}{#3}\mright)_{\mkern-6mu#1}} 

\begin{document}

 \[ \Leg{\pi }{\sigma}\quad \Leg[3]{\pi }{\theta}\quad \Leg{\theta}{\pi} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I've changed your syntax a bit: The optional argument now is a size command and your index is mandatory. Just play around with the sizes you like.

The problem with your command is that you automatically apply auto-sizing (left and right), which will not result in same output if different input is given (especially with different sizes).

Btw: You should use `\[...\]` instead of the `$$` syntax.

[image: sizes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Leg}[4][big]{\csname #1l\endcsname(\frac{#3}{#4}\csname#1r\endcsname)_{#2}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \Leg[Bigg]{3}{\pi}{\theta} = \Leg[Bigg]{3}{\theta}{\pi}
\]
\[
    \Leg{3}{\pi}{\theta} = \Leg{3}{\theta}{\pi}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the `\csname` business? I read the body of your code without reading the preamble, and was very surprised to see `\Leg[Bigg]`, which differs from the standard mathtools syntax. What about `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\@Leg}{(}{)} \newcommand*{\Leg}[4][\big]{\@Leg[#1]{\frac{#3}{#4}}_{#2}}`, optionally adding `\@ifstar` support for `\@Leg*`?

Comment: (Though `\genfrac` still seems cleaner to me—this is its purpose, after all.)

Comment: @wchargin To use the left and right delimiters without additional packages. I know that you may use mathtools, but sometimes simple LaTeX is very sufficient ;) And yes, genfrac seems clearer (didn't come to my mind at that point).

Comment: Sorry for off, but could you explain why `\[`...`\]` is preferable over `$$`?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - I was curious too - this seems to be the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/112443

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to.

Comment: @Itai Not quite. See above.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an alternative that allows you to still use automatic scaling.  It defines a `\Legmatch` command, with an additional two dummy arguments.  These give the other Legendre expression whose size this one should match.

Internally, it inserts a `\vphantom` box, with the same height as the contents of the contents of the other expression and zero width, inside the paired delimiters.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\Legmatch}[5][]{\left(\vphantom{\frac{#4}{#5}}\frac{#2}{#3}\right)_{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\[
   \Legmatch[3]{\pi}{\theta^{\frac{\alpha^2}{2}}}{\theta}{\pi} =
   \Legmatch[3]{\theta}{\pi}{\pi}{\theta^{\frac{\alpha^2}{2}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Matching Legendre expressions]

I particularly like Bernard’s answer, which uses `mleftright`.  This one might still come in handy in a few special cases, such as if you want to split lines or introduce other struts on the same line.