# Is `\[` equivalent to \begin{displaymath}?

Tags: math-mode

Are the following two code snippets equivalent?

## Snippet One

```
\[
    a + b = c 
\]
```

## Snippet Two

```
\begin{displaymath}
    a + b = c 
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854) seems relevant to your question.

Comment: see also this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/36296

Comment: The answer is (effectively) "yes" by the way :).