# Unwanted Line Break after product symbol

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I wrote an equation with 3 products involved and it doesn't seem that they want to be written in one line (pic related). My code looks like this:

```
\begin{center}  
$\psi$ =   
$$\prod_{i=1}^{x}$$ $\times$   
$$\prod_{i=1}^{y}$$ $\times$   
$$\prod_{i=1}^{z}$$   
\end{center}
```

I am new to Latex and I don't know what I did wrong. [image]Thanks for your help!

Comment: Everything between every first `$$` and the next `$$` will be a displayed equation in a line of its own. That's how TeX works. If you want the product symbols in the same line, put them all between the same `$$`...`$$` pair: `$$\prod_{i=1}^{x} \times \prod_{i=1}^{y}$$`. And don't use `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}` there.

Comment: Also have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179052/120578

Comment: Thank you, it's fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to typeset a displayed equation, i.e., an equation on a row by itself. If that's the case, you should be writing

```
\[ 
\psi = \prod_{i=1}^{x} \times \prod_{i=1}^{y} \times \prod_{i=1}^{z}   
\]
```

The `\[` and `\]` directives serve to initiate and terminate display math mode. Observe that there aren't any `$` or `$$` directives between `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: A look at this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/579 might also be useful.