# Latex does not go to next line

Tags: math-mode, indentation

I am working on a document for school, trying to make some equations lines. However, the double dollar command for making equations omits the next line command.

```
$$
    S(k+1)  &= \sum(a[i]\cdot a[j] \mid i,j : 0\leq i\leq j < k + 1)\\
            &=
$$
```

I would expect the equation to go to the next line and continue indentation from the `=` character, however the document shows me this:

[image]

I have tried disabling packages but this offers no solution.

When I started working in this document there were no issues, a few hours later it suddenly stopped working correctly.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `$$` should never be used in LaTeX. In your case, substitute them with `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

This cannot work: the construct `$$ ····· $$` (which anyway is a plain TeX construction and should be replaced in LaTeX with `\[ ····· \]`) is for a one-line centred equation.

For what you want you should use the amsmath `align` (lines numbered) or `align*`(unnumbered), with the alignment point specified with an ampersand. For other types of multiline equations, please take a look at the documentation of `amsmath`, or its extension `mathtools`.

Answer (score 6):

For reasons *not* to use `$$` to start and stop an unnumbered displayed equation in a LaTeX document, see [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)  For still more information on this subject, see [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Anyway, all you need to do to salvage your code is to replace the first instance of `$$` with `\begin{align*}` and the second instance of `$$` with `\end{align*}`.

While you're at it, though, you may want to enlarge the `(`, `|`, and `)` delimiters, and you may want to either replace `:` with `\colon` or use double-sum notation. Both options are pursued in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  S(k+1)  
    &= \sum \bigl( a[i] \cdot a[j] \bigm| i,j \colon 0 \leq i \leq j < k + 1 \bigr) \\
    &= \sum_{i = 0}^j \sum_{j = 0}^{k + 1} \bigl( a[i] \cdot a[j] \bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner - Thanks for the updates. :-)