# What are the ways of centering the math formula

Tags: math-mode

I am beginner at latex, and I am wondering how should I make the math formula centered. What I want is as shown on the picture. Also what is the best way of making spaces when writing math code? I am reffering to the spaces between min and f(x). Thanks in advance[image]

My code looks like this, but there are a few problems
1) P should be in the middle of these lines and on the left of both.
2) spaces between min s.t, are there any other ways than writing a lot of \:

```
\begin{align} 
(P)\:\: minf(x)\\ 
s.t\:\:g(x,s)\leq 0\:\:\forall s\in\Omega 
\end{align}
```

Comment: Without code hard to tell...

Comment: Welcome. Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are many ways to typeset an equation displayed on a line by itself, usually (but not necessarily) centered on the line. The same goes for multi-line equations. Does the posting [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) offer some useful pointers?

Comment: I would suggest you start by look at the documentation for the [`amsmath` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).  Try some of their code, and if you get stuck, make your question more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it may help you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{gather*}
(P) \qquad\begin{aligned}
        \min    &\quad   f(x)        \\
\mathrm{s.t}    &\quad   g(x,s)\leq 0\:\:\forall s\in\Omega
          \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```