# multiple lines in math display

Tags: equations

happy new year i want your help i would like to show which one below with a new line or one below each other but i can't find how to do it the code is here

```
$$\bm{X}=[ \bm{x}^{(1)} , \bm{x}^{(2)} ,\ldots ,\bm{x}^{(m)} ] \in \mathbb{R}^{(n,m} \bm{B}=[ \bm{b}^{(1)} , \bm{b}^{(2)}, \ldots , \bm{b}^{(m)}]  \in\mathbb{R}^{(n.m)} $$
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding your use of `$$` you might want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/134144

Comment: Apart from that, please make  your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: Does `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\bm{X}&=[ \bm{x}^{(1)} , \bm{x}^{(2)} ,\ldots ,\bm{x}^{(m)} ] \in \mathbb{R}^{(n,m}\\ \bm{B}&=[ \bm{b}^{(1)} , \bm{b}^{(2)}, \ldots , \bm{b}^{(m)}]  \in\mathbb{R}^{(n.m)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}` give you the desired result?

Comment: @leandriis, till to now i didn't observe your comment :-(. Sorry! If you will convert it to an answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: @Zarko: No problem: Let's keep your answer.

Comment: @leandriis, thank you very much! Happy New Year!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bm{X} & =[ \bm{x}^{(1)}, \bm{x}^{(2)}, \ldots, \bm{x}^{(m)}] \in \mathbb{R}^{(n.m)} \\
\bm{B} & =[ \bm{b}^{(1)}, \bm{b}^{(2)}, \ldots, \bm{b}^{(m)}] \in\mathbb{R}^{(n.m)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: you will make New Year Happy to us if you will in future questions always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example: a small complete document, which reproduce your problem) and with it help us to help you!