# Align number irrespective of sign in the cases environment

Tags: align, amsmath, cases

I want to align numbers 1 and -1 in irrespective of sign in the environment `cases`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Decision function}
$$
h_{w,b}(x) = g(w^\top x + b)
$$
$$
g(w^\top x + b) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } w^\top x + b > 0\\
-1 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried `\begin{cases*}\end{cases*}` and `\begin{cases}[d]\end{cases}` but it didn't work

Comment: In this specific example there is a dirty hack: replace 1 by \phantom{-}1 in the first case.

Comment: For a more generic solution, you can use \begin{array}{rl} ... \end{array} where rl means : 1st column aligned right, second column aligned left

Comment: thanks for your comment @Arnaud. I tried `\phantom{-}`, but the minus  disappears and the 1 are still misaligned. For the `array` environment, I'll be happy to try your proposition. Could you write a full example?

Comment: Sorry @Arnaud, I musunderstood. I had put the phantom in from of the wrong 1. It worked. Many thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: you should not  use the plain TeX contruct `$$ … $$`, but the LaTeX construct `\[ … \]`, or better here, nest your equations in the amsmath  `gather*` environment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Bernard. I find easier to write `$$..$$` instead of `\[..\]` where you also sometime have to chase the missing `\]`. What is according to you the advantage of `\[\]`?

Comment: There is a post on this subject here, but as far as I remember, the  spacing  with $$ … $$ is not correct in LaTeX. Anyway, easiness in typing is just an editor problem . My personal shortcut for `\[ \]` (with the cursor between the brackets!) is simply Alt+$, for instance.

Comment: @ecjb - See [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) for a deeper discussion of why `\[...\]` is preferred over `$$...$$` for LaTeX documents.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the feedback, I'll study the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below code helps:

```
\begin{align*}
h_{w,b}(x) & = g(w^\top x + b)
\\
g(w^\top x + b) &= \begin{cases}
\phantom{-}1 & \text{if } w^\top x + b > 0\\
-1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Saravanan. But actually what I want to align are the 1 and -1 in the cases environment. Not the equal sign of the 2  equations

Comment: I have updated the equation above.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that employs `\hfill` rather than `\phantom{-}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' env.
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{2}

\subsection{Decision function}
\begin{gather*}
h_{w,b}(x) = g(w^{\top\!} x + b) \\
g(w^{\top\!} x + b) = 
\begin{cases}
\hfill 1 & \text{if $w^{\top\!} x + b > 0$}\\
-1       & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of `mathtools` you can define as many variants of `cases` as you want. Here I define `casesr` and siblings:

- `casesr` is like `cases`, but with right alignment in the left column;
- `dcasesr` uses display style;
- `casesr*` and `dcasesr*` are the same as above, but the right column is typeset in text mode.

In your case, `casesr*` is the best choice.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcases{casesr}
  {\quad}% space between columns
  {\hfil$\m@th##$}% left column is right aligned
  {$\m@th##$\hfil}% right column is left aligned
  {\lbrace}% left delimiter
  {.}% right delimiter
\newcases{dcasesr}
  {\quad}% space between columns
  {\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}% left column is right aligned
  {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}% right column is left aligned
  {\lbrace}% left delimiter
  {.}% right delimiter
\newcases{casesr*}
  {\quad}% space between columns
  {\hfil$\m@th##$}% left column is right aligned
  {##\hfil}% right column is left aligned, text mode
  {\lbrace}% left delimiter
  {.}% right delimiter
\newcases{dcasesr*}
  {\quad}% space between columns
  {\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}% left column is right aligned
  {##\hfil}% right column is left aligned, text mode
  {\lbrace}% left delimiter
  {.}% right delimiter
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection{Decision function}
\begin{gather*}
h_{w,b}(x) = g(w^\top x + b)
\\
g(w^\top x + b) = 
\begin{casesr*}
1 & if $w^\top x + b > 0$\\
-1 & otherwise
\end{casesr*}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Never use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)