# Exercise disappears after adding equation (exercise package)

Tags: align, exercises, pdfsync

I'm having a weird problem with the following document:

The preamble consist of

```
    \documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{amsart}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{exercise}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    %\usepackage{baskervald}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{xstring}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{gauss}
    \usepackage{bbm}
    \usepackage{pdfsync}

    \setlist[enumerate]{label=(\roman*)}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    \newcommand{\set}[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\{ #1 \}}{\{ #1 \text{ } | \text{ } #2 \}}}

    \title{Exam in Integration Theory \\ 2020-01-14}
    \author{Jonathan Lindell}
```

Then I have

```
    \begin{document}
... some other exercises to get to this one. 
        \begin{Exercise}
          Suppose that \(\set{a_n}{}\) is a sequence of non-negative numbers and \(\set{E_n}{}\) a sequence of Lebesgue measurable subsets of \([0,1]\). Supppose there exists \(\delta > 0\) such that \(m(E_n) \geq \delta\) and
          \begin{align*}
            \sum_{n}a_n\chi_{E_n}(x) < \infty
          \end{align*}
          for Lebesgue a.e. \(x\). Prove that
          \begin{align*}
            \sum_{n} a_n < \infty
          \end{align*}
        \end{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, the whole exercise disappers. If I remove the last align the document compiles as normal. 
[image: The whole code]
[image: If I remove the last align]

I am using emacs to write the tex code in auctex. I have tried to compile it directly in the terminal using pdflatex, though no difference. If I compile just the code I have posted I get the same problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) As it stands there is no way of telling what is going wrong. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Okay, I tried to add a minimal working example now. Hopefully it is enough. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Drop the `pdfsync` package (since we got synctex build into the engine, this package have been irrelevant). BTW 1: make your MWE into a single piece of code not two sniplets. BTW 2: you are loading a lot of packages that are irrelevant for showing the issue. BTW 3: you might want to have a look at the `\Set` example in the `mathtools` manual, it provides a (IMO) better syntax for sets than a two arg macro.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help :) it works if I just drop pdfsync. Thank you for all tips in general

Comment: From the user guide of the `pdfsync` package: *pdfsync uses extremely [sensitive] code. You should not use pdfsync on final documents because it can change the layout rather significantly (different page/line breaks are the most obvious changes), ... Murphy’s law states that it will happen to you when it absolutely must not...*

Comment: Some general comments about your code: (a) You appear to have considerable fondness for using `align*` environments. You should *not* use them to create single-line unnumbered displaymath environments; use `\[ ... \]` instead. See the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001) for more information on this topic. (b) The `hyperref` package should be loaded *last*. (c) The `amsfonts` package is loaded automatically by the `amssymb` package; hence, no need to load `amsfonts` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the general comments regarding my tex code. Is there a guide or tutorial you recommend for learning to write better documents in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue goes away if you drop the `pdfsync` package. I have no idea what the problem is, but `pdfsync` have not been relevant for a very long time by now.