# How to typeset the following equation?

Tags: equations, text

How do writers typeset their equations of the form (EQUATION), (WORDS)(EQUATION), where the latter part usually serves as a condition or explanations?

For example,
[image: example]

Is the only way of doing this to write something like
$$\begin{...}\;\;\;\text{ for some }\gamma...$$?

Comment: `\[ \alpha \mbox{ and } \omega  \]`

Comment: @Fran thanks a lot

Comment: What's wrong with it? There are more separators than \; Often \hfill works fine for me to put the condition at the  right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is that, yes. However it's better to use a predefined spacing command rather than arbitrary rows of `\;` commands (that are for different things).

You can improve your style by using some personal command: I defined `\Mat` for a set of matrices (with an upright M) and `\ZZ` for the integers.

The reason for the indirect definition is that if you have several number sets to deal with, just changing the main command `\numberset` to use, say, `\mathbf`, you'll get *all* number sets updated and don't need to change each one of them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{M}
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\numberset{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} P \\ Q \end{bmatrix}
= \gamma \begin{bmatrix} \omega_1/N + \Lambda \\ \omega_2/N + \Lambda \end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{for some $\gamma \in \Mat_2(\ZZ/N\ZZ)$}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `\text{M}`: it is wrong in this context; for example, the M would be in italic in the statement of a theorem. Also `\tag` is for a very different purpose and should not be abused.

Answer (score 3):

If you meant for the equation to be in display mode, you can use `\tag*`. For example:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is an equation:
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    P\\ 
    Q
\end{bmatrix}
= \gamma
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_1/N + \Lambda \\
    \omega_2/N + \Lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag*{for some $\gamma \in \text{M}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z})$}
\]
\end{document}
```

The above code yields:

[image: Minimal working example]

Note that `\tag*` does not include parentheses. To include surrounding parentheses in the tagged remark, remove the asterisk from the command (i.e., use `\tag`).

As an aside, avoid using `$$...$$` in display math mode, as it is heavily discouraged. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath) for very good explanations why.

Comment: +1 for your effort. I will put a \text because it is not a tag. There is the M in roman-mode.

Comment: Good catch! Fixed it.

Comment: LOL :-)  the cooperation is important.

Comment: The text is *not* a tag.  `\tag` is intended for a label (on a display) that doesn't follow the normal/default style.