# what is problem of running this page?

Tags: errors, header-footer, document-classes

[image]

this page doesn't run !
what is the problem here in package

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allosw others to reproduce the output you get. Showing code as an image makes it quite hard to test suggestions.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but regarding your use of `$$`, you might nevertheless want to take a look at [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/134144) and [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/134144)

Comment: It looks like the document class may fail to define a page style called `myheadings`. Which document class do you employ?

Comment: You are using a document class which does not define the `myheadings` page style. Change document class or delete `\pagestyle{myheadings}`

Comment: @Mico i defined this package in the main page                                                                    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twosided]{book}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{xthesis}
\usepackage{xtocinc}
\pagestyle{headings} \hfuzz2pt

Comment: you are trying to compile the chapter file. Set the main file as "main file", so that it is compiled.

Comment: Please follow up on what @leandriis has asked you to do -- to post not just a screenshot of some code, but the actual code that gives rise to the issue you're looking to fix.

Comment: In your comment, you mention that `\pagestyle{headings}` is in the preamble, yet the screenshot you posted says something about the `myheadings` style not being found. Please clarify.

Comment: it runs with me ,thanks for your guides

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I'm voting to close this question because suggestions given i comments were acknowledged by OP to solve the problem.