# Can't align center equation

Tags: equations

Im a fresh new user of LaTex and I have to write a short mathematic report.
I found a solution reading my manual but I can't solve the following problem, this is the interested piece of code

```
Sia \textbf{$\delta$b$\in$$\mathbb{R}$$^{n}$} 
il vettore delle perturbazioni dei termini noti del sistema

\begin{equation} \label{sys_eq}
A(x)=b
\end{equation}

e si indichi con

x + $\delta$x

la soluzione del sistema perturbato, avremo

\begin{displaymath}
$$ A(x+$\delta$x)=b+$\delta$b $$
\end{displaymath}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see the first equation is properly centered, but I tried everything to center the second one without success. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: displaymath is a math environment delete all the `$`

Comment: You are switching in and out of math mode a lot. In general you want to write one logical term/one equation in one math environment. `\begin{displaymath}
$$ A(x+$\delta$x)=b+$\delta$b $$
\end{displaymath}` should just be `\begin{displaymath}
A(x+ \delta x)=b+ \delta b
\end{displaymath}`. Similarly `x + $\delta$x` should be `$x + \delta x$`.

Comment: @moewe yep I have deleted my comment as I noticed that!!

Comment: `\textbf{$\delta$b$\in$$\mathbb{R}$$^{n}$} ` also looks wrong. I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but I'm guessing it is more like `$\delta \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$`.

Comment: The reason why the second equation (a) isn't centered and (b) is placed far away from the material that precedes it is because `\begin{displaymath}` is cancelled by the first instance of `$$`, while the second instance of `$$` cancels out `\end{displaymath}`. For more information on the properties of `$$`, `\begin{displaymath}`, and `\end{displaymath}` see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/5001) -- shameless self-citation alert! -- to the question [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete most of the blank lines and `$` then you get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

Sia $\delta b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
il vettore delle perturbazioni dei termini noti del sistema
\begin{equation} \label{sys_eq}
A(x)=b
\end{equation}
e si indichi con $x + \delta x$
la soluzione del sistema perturbato, avremo
\begin{displaymath}
A(x+\delta x)=b+\delta b 
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Although perhaps you wanted to make b bold, it was not clear from the original markup.

Comment: You should mention that you removed the blank lines from around the displays in the input, and say why.