# Inconsistency between equation and \[ \]

Tags: math-mode

While answering another question, I noticed that the definition for `\begin{equation}` is:

```
\def\equation{$$\refstepcounter{equation}}
```

Shouldn't `\begin{equation}` include the following like unnumbered display math does?

```
\ifvmode
    \nointerlineskip
    \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
\fi
```

Comment: possibly but can't really change the spacing after all this time. any document with mathematics ought be using amsmath, which redefines `\[` to be `\begin{equation*}` closer to `equation`

Comment: The whole `\ifvmode` etc. incantation is absent from amsmath. Kind of makes the argument against `$$`...`$$` lose some of its punch.

Comment: the main argument against `$$` is non-support of fleqn,

Comment: Ah, good point, I always forget about that. Taking a glance over the results on searching for fleqn here, it looks like a lot of package/class writers forget about it as well.

Comment: The points you raise are also examined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/5001) (shameless self-citation alert!) to the query [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be answered in the comments.